# How do I get the filepath for a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, introspection

Given a class `C` in Python, how can I determine which file the class was defined in? I need something that can work from either the class `C`, or from an instance of `C`.

I am doing this because I am generally a fan of putting files that belong together in the same folder. I want to create a class that uses a Django template to render itself as HTML. The base implementation should infer the filename for the template based on the filename that the class is defined in.

Say I put a class `LocationArtifact` in the file "base/artifacts.py", then I want the default behaviour to be that the template name is "base/LocationArtifact.html".

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602846/how-can-i-access-the-current-executing-module-or-class-name-in-python

Comment: Those assume you know the module you are looking up the file for, I will just have the module string as I work with implementations off a class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the location of Python module sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can use the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile) module, like this:

```
import inspect
inspect.getfile(C.__class__)
```

Comment: Not sure what I was doing different but instead of `getfile` I had to use:  `inspect.getmodule(C.__class__)`

Comment: Note: does not work on a classes created by the user

Comment: This should probably be `inspect.getfile(C)`. If `C` is a class, then `C.__class__` refers to `object`, which will raise an exception `TypeError: <module 'builtins' (built-in)> is a built-in class`. I think that only for an instance `c` do you want to use `inspect.getfile(c.__class__)`.

Comment: This did not for a class that extends an abstract base class (`metaclass=abc.ABCMeta`), as it returns `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/abc.py` instead of the appropriate file.  The solution by @JarretHardie (below) worked better.

Comment: The accepted answer: *guaranteed to be the wrong answer.* It's a StackOverflow tradition by now.

Answer (score 50):

try:

```
import sys, os
os.path.abspath(sys.modules[LocationArtifact.__module__].__file__)
```

Comment: To get the path from an instance of C (as desired by the OP), replace `LocationArtifact` with `obj.__class__` where obj is an instance of LocationArtifact.

Comment: This also works for meta classes!

Comment: inspect take alot resources, this is perfect

Comment: **This is the way.** `inspect` should *generally* be avoided in production code. It's slow. It's fragile. It fails in common edge cases. If you can't write a one-liner that does it, you probably shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 5):

This is the wrong approach for Django and really forcing things.

The typical Django app pattern is:

- **/project**

  - **/appname**

    - models.py
    - views.py
    - **/templates**

      - index.html
      - etc.

Comment: +1: Do what Django does naturally and life is so much simpler.

Comment: Agreed.  Django is one of the frameworks with the least amount of "magic", but templates, template tags and apps have some expectations as part of their pattern.  If you're having to do wacky class inference you're probably going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the error to get the path of your class

```
import os
import traceback
class C:
  def getClassPath(self):
    #get foldet path
    try:
        raise ValueError("Example error")
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.extract_tb(e.__traceback__)
       
        return os.path.dirname(tb[-1].filename)
c = C()
print('path is',c.getClassPath())
```