# python how to find which parent classes define methods of a child object

Tags: python

For context, I will use the example that prompted this question which is the DNA sequence class of Scikit-Bio.

The base class is a generic python sequence class. A Sequence class inherits from that class for sequences that are specifically nucleic acids (DNA, RNA ...). Finally, there is a DNA class that inherits from Sequence that enforces the specific alphabet of DNA.

So the following codes lists all the attributes of a DNA object.

```
from skbio import DNA

d = DNA('ACTGACTG')
for attr in dir(d):
    # All the attributes of d.
```

How can I find which parent class each attribute belongs to? The reason why I am interested in this is that I am looking through the source code, and I want to be able to know which file I can find each method that I want to look at.

The best I can think of is something like this:

```
for attr in dir(d)
    print type(attr)
```

But this just returns all string types (I guess dir() returns a list of strings).

How can I achieve this in python? Is there an inherent reason to not attemps this at all? Or is this something that comes up often in OOP?

Comment: The `__mro__` attribute of a class is a tuple of its bases, in **m**ethod **r**esolution **o**rder, if that's what you're after. You can find the file for a class as follows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/697395/3001761

Comment: You are probably better off grepping once you have a list of things you are interested in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961048/get-class-that-defined-method

Comment: @KamilSokołowski not quite, that's how to get the file once you have the class itself

Comment: For your final code fragment, try `for attr in dir(d): print type(getattr(d, attr))`.

Comment: @Robᵩ that worked, and it further illustrated your answer because all of the methods are of type 'instancemethod'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes don't typically *belong* to any class. Attributes typically belong to the object of which they are an attribute.

Methods, however, relate intimately to the class in which they are defined.

Consider this program:

```
class base(object):
    def create_attrib_a(self):
        self.a = 1
class derived(base):
    def create_attrib_b(self):
        self.b = 1
def create_attrib_c(obj):
   obj.c = 1

import inspect

o = derived()
o.create_attrib_a()
o.create_attrib_b()
create_attrib_c(o)
o.d = 1

# The objects attributes are relatively anonymous
print o.__dict__

# But the class's methods have lots of information available
for name, value in inspect.getmembers(o, inspect.ismethod):
    print 'Method=%s, filename=%s, line number=%d'%(
        name,
        value.im_func.func_code.co_filename,
        value.im_func.func_code.co_firstlineno)
```

As you can see, each of the attributes `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are associated with the object bound to `o`. None of them relate, in any technical sense, to any specific class.

However, the methods `create_attrib_a` and `create_attrib_b` carry precisely the information you desire. See how the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module can retrieve the filename and line number of their definition.

Comment: Interesting so there is no way to find out which class "create_attrib_a" was defined in just given the object?

Comment: There is no (practical) way to find which class's code defined `a`. There are ways to find the class that defined `create_attrib_a`. Methods (like `create_attrib_a` have more data available than attributes (like `a`). Are you saying that you are interested in the methods?

Comment: @Malonge , see my recent edit for how to find the source code for the methods.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this!