# Finding which script contains a particular function or class

Tags: python, module

> How can I find out the file path and correct script containing a particular function or class of a module?

---

**Example:** Say I want to take  a look at the tkinter source code for `tkinter.Button()`.

I found where the `__init__.py` file is located for tkinter using:

```
>>>import tkinter
>>>tkinter.__file__
'C:\\Users\\Simon\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\tkinter\\__init__.py'
```

I searched through that folder but was unable to locate any function or class named `Button`.  My guess that it is contained inside the run-times and not a `.py` file but I am not definite and want to be *sure* of this.

I could not find anything useful in the [Python documentation special attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) either.

*Any suggestions are welcome but please note that this post is not set only on the tkinter module but most packages or modules, tkinter just being an example.*

Comment: Not all classes in Python are implemented in as Python code, some things are implemented in natively compiled extensions. `tkinter` objects are exposed in Python from a C library called `Tk`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Thank you.  So I would need to look at the C source and not the Python code for the `Button()` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tkinter` objects are not implemented as Python source code. See the [`tkinter` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html):

> The Tk interface is located in a binary module named _tkinter. This module contains the low-level interface to Tk, and should never be used directly by application programmers. It is usually a shared library (or DLL), but might in some cases be statically linked with the Python interpreter.

See the [Tcl/Tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/) the `tkinter` library documentation links to. The Tcl/Tk documentation in turn links to https://core.tcl.tk/, the central hub for development of that project (which is external to Python).

Following links from there you can find the [GitHub mirror of the project source code](https://github.com/tcltk/), which includes the [Tk source](https://github.com/tcltk/), where you can find the [`tkButton.c` source file](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/generic/tkButton.c); this is the core button widget implementation.

There is some [Python code involved as well](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py), but the class definitions there are mostly there to just pass on commands to the native Tk library.

Comment: So if I want to look at the `Button()` class I need to go lower level.  Thank you very much for your detailed post.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions are welcome but please note that this post is not set only on the >tkinter module but most packages or modules, tkinter just being an example.

This pretty much answers your question (for general cases) [How do I get the filepath for a class in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697320/how-do-i-get-the-filepath-for-a-class-in-python)

One can also see that Class Button(Widget) *is* defined in the **init**, but this is a wrapper as @Martijn Pieters wrote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was helpful to me so I have up-voted it and since it does answer my second question, but have accepted that of @Martijn Pieters because it describes why it is not possible with `tkinter` and where `Button()` is actually located.  Thank you once again.