# tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create buttons in tkinter within a `for` loop. And with each loop pass the `i` count value out as an argument in the command value. So when the function is called from the `command` value I can tell which button was pressed and act accordingly.

The problem is, say the length is 3, it will create 3 buttons with titles <kbd>**Game 1**</kbd> through <kbd>**Game 3**</kbd> but when any of the buttons are pressed the printed value is always `2`, the last iteration. So it appears the buttons are being made as separate entities, but the `i` value in the command arguments seem to be all the same. Here is the code:

```
def createGameURLs(self):
    self.button = []
    for i in range(3):
        self.button.append(Button(self, text='Game '+str(i+1),
                                  command=lambda: self.open_this(i)))
        self.button[i].grid(column=4, row=i+1, sticky=W)

def open_this(self, myNum):
    print(myNum)
```

Is there a way to get the current `i` value, each iteration, to stick with that particular button?

---

<sub>This problem can be considered a special case of [Creating functions in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676). There's also [What do lambda function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290), for a more technical overview.</sub>

<sub>See also [How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302) for the general problem of passing arguments to Button callbacks.</sub>

Comment: A big thanks to both of you LukaD and BrenBarn, I have been fighting with that for several days now believe it or not. Both ways worked perfectly. I went with the i=i fix for now, but I'm definitely going to read up on the functools. I appreciate both answers.

Comment: If BrenBarns solution works for you then you should mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: @martineau Do you believe that the duplicate question answers this question?

Comment: @Delrius: Oops, no, I accidentally marked it as a dup. and of the wrong question. Thanks for bring the mistake to to my attention.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19693782/4014959

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: @Julien That's quite unnecessary, the problem is clear from the code presented.

Answer (score 164):

Change your lambda to `lambda i=i: self.open_this(i)`.

This may look magical, but here's what's happening.  When you use that lambda to define your function, the open_this call doesn't get the value of the variable i at the time you define the function.  Instead, it makes a closure, which is sort of like a note to itself saying "I should look for what the value of the variable i is *at the time that I am called*".  Of course, the function is called after the loop is over, so at that time i will always be equal to the last value from the loop.

Using the `i=i` trick causes your function to store the current value of i at the time your lambda is defined, instead of waiting to look up the value of i later.

Comment: what if we wanted to pass two arguments to a function like open_this?

Comment: @Amen: It depends what you want those arguments to be.  If both are coming from some external loop and you want to "freeze" them both in way shown above, you would just do `lambda x=x, y=y: self.open_this(x, y)`.

Comment: This is brilliant, straightforward and good explanation. This should be the answer.

Comment: @BrenBarn Just now i came across same situation, its really amazing. I really weird how you all came across these kind of techniques. Thank you so much.

Comment: at first this did not make sense. Kudos!

Comment: Has that `lambda i=i: ....` syntax always been available in python?   I never saw that before, but seeing how the answer is dated 8 years ago, I guess it's been around a while.  I could have used that more than once in my travels!

Comment: @RufusVS: It's just default argument syntax.  It's the same as when you do `def foo(x, y=3)`.  It's just that here the name of the function argument is the same as the name of a variable in the enclosing scope.

Comment: @BrenBarn  it's funny, but I never made that connection with lambda functions, of just taking the parenthesized arguments of a  regular function and place them before the colon of the lambda function!  I'm sure I won't forget it now.

Comment: @RufusVS `lambda` functions are just anonymous functions.  You can still use arguments/parameters with it, just like any function.  See [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions) for a little more information.

Comment: "_Using the i=i trick causes your function to store the current value_", I think of it more like it creates a new function over each loop whose arguments are stored in the newly created functions, dont know if this is correct :)

Comment: @CoolCloud: That is the same as what I said.  You said "the arguments are stored in the functions".  I said "the function stores the value".  It's the same thing.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly and the explanation was great ;). Thank you so much.

Comment: It bothers me to no end that "deliberately exploit [one of the most famous gotchas in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/)" is the popular solution for this while "use a standard library tool specifically designed for the purpose of binding parameters" (i.e., `functools.partial`) is practically forgotten.

Answer (score 12):

This is how closures work in python. I ran into this problem myself once.
You could use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this.

```
for i in range(3):
    self.button.append(Button(self, text='Game '+str(i+1), command=partial(self.open_this, i)))
```

Comment: seemed easy, if you are using virtual environments you might get an issue, refer to the first on: `self.button.append(Button(self, text='Game ' + str(i + 1), command=lambda x=i: self.open_this(x)))`

Comment: @Lucem "if you are using virtual environments you might get an issue" There is no good reason why, as `functools.partial` is part of the standard library and has been for a long time. If you had difficulty with it then you should try to diagnose the problem and ask your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Simply attach your buttons scope within a lambda function like this:

`btn["command"] = lambda btn=btn: click(btn)` where `click(btn)` is the function that passes in the button itself. 
This will create a binding scope from the button to the function itself.

Features:

- Customize gridsize
- Responsive resizing
- Toggle active state

---

```
#Python2
#from Tkinter import *
#import Tkinter as tkinter
#Python3
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

root = Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
grid=Frame(frame)
grid.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W, column=0, row=7, columnspan=2)
Grid.rowconfigure(frame, 7, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(frame, 0, weight=1)

active="red"
default_color="white"

def main(height=5,width=5):
  for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
      btn = tkinter.Button(frame, bg=default_color)
      btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=N+S+E+W)
      btn["command"] = lambda btn=btn: click(btn)

  for x in range(width):
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)

  for y in range(height):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)

  return frame

def click(button):
  if(button["bg"] == active):
    button["bg"] = default_color
  else:
    button["bg"] = active

w= main(10,10)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because the value for the name `i` changes and isn't captured by `lambda:`. (You can try that theory out by adding `i = 1234` after the loop and seeing what happens.)

You'll need to write a function to wrap that `i` as a local name, then return a lambda in that function that captures `i` .

```
def make_button_click_command(i):
    return lambda: button_click(i)

# ...

btn = Button(..., command=make_button_click_command(i))
```

Another option is `functools.partial`, which does effectively the same thing:

```
command=functools.partial(button_click, i)
```

All in all, you can also simplify things a bit by using just `range` to get numbers from 0 to 10 and `divmod` to get the row and column in one function call:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button


def button_click(i):
    print(i)


def make_button_click_command(i):
    return lambda: button_click(i)


root = Tk()

for i in range(10):
    value = (i + 1) % 10
    row, col = divmod(i, 3)
    btn = Button(root, text=value, padx=40, pady=20, command=make_button_click_command(value))
    btn.grid(row=row + 1, column=col)

root.mainloop()
```