# How to show the correct number of buttons in GUI based on the number of items in the array?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

By referring to [Python tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/python-tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments) , I modified the code to become like this:

```
self.listarray = ["Option A", "Option B", "Option C", "Option D"]
for i in range(len(self.listarray)):
    self.buttonlist.append(tk.Button(self, text=self.listarray[i], command=lambda i=i: self.printthis(i)))
    self.buttonlist[i].grid(column=1, row=i+1, sticky="W")
self.mainloop()

def printthis(self, thenum):
    print thenum
    self.destroy()
```

so that there will be four buttons of "Option A", "Option B", and so on...

But, what happened was that my window freezes and unable to do anything. So I closed it.

This is not a problem when I changed this line:

```
self.buttonlist[i].grid(column=1, row=i+1, sticky="W")
```

become this

```
self.buttonlist[i].pack()
```

But I want to customise the location of my button as well. Which part of my codes are wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of your code that is wrong is the part where you use both `grid` and `pack` for widgets that have the same parent. You can use only one or the other. If you want to use `grid` for the buttons, you must use `grid` for every widget that has the same parent.