# Issue with button command on Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, lambda

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *

class Thing:

    var = {}
    def item(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        # Settings of main window
        things = [] # Array which contains items with different values
        for thing in things:
            # 1*
            self.var[f'b{thing}'] = Button(self.root, text='Test',command = lambda: self.remove(thing))
            self.var[f'b{thing}'].pack()

    def remove(self, thing=None):
        print(thing)
        # 2*
Thing().item()
```

**Question**

When I press for the first time any button, the class `remove` print the correct value, when I try to press another button, the class 'remove' print another time the first value instead of second.
I'm thinking that the issue is in buttons command.
I appreciate every kind of help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/python-tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)

Comment: Try replacing with ...`lambda t=thing: self.remove(t))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use lambda in a loop like that. You will have to use `functools.partial`.

```
from functools import partial
#...
self.var[f'b{thing}'] = Button(self.root, text='Test',command = partial(self.remove, thing))
```