# Is it possible to color a button by clicking, while having multiple other buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I wanted to create a game called "battleship". For this, I have to allow the user to place his ships.
I wanted to try this by allowing the user to color a field where the ship has to be placed. My problem is, that I have created 15 x 15 variables in a list by using 2 for loops. Is there actually a command possibility to for example get the row and the column of the grid, because this part, for example, will always give me the last `i` and the last `j` I have asked for. Otherwise, I would have to create 225 lines, 
by mentioning the `i` and `j` when using `lambda`.

```
self.ship[i][j] = tk.Button(root, text="", padx=30, pady=20, command=lambda:color(i,j))
self.ship[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)
```

Comment: the full code I cannot post, because it is actually a homework , is it k for posting a part of the code, like the function?

Comment: Since this question closed before I had time to answer, please have a look at my solution for your problem: [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59964520/2902996)

Comment: I am very grateful for your post, I also have tried it to use. I will look today evening, what I can use of your code, since you are using something I have not learned yet.

Comment: Thank you, don't hesistate to ask me any questions if you need clarification. Essentially, if you do not want the responsive stuff, you can just do `btn["command"] = lambda btn=btn: click(btn)` where `click(btn)` is the function. This will create a binding scope from the button to the function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following code gives you a good starting point to go ahead with your game.

I have used the same approach of using two for loops to create a `10x10 grid` of buttons. Then i have used an `click event callback` to get the widget that is being clicked upon and then make the selected button blue or perform any operation on that widget.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Game:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable(0,0)
        # row index
        for row in range(10):
            # col index
            for col in range(10):
                self.button = tk.Button(master, width=1, height=1)
                self.button.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=8, pady=8, ipadx=10, ipady=4)
                self.button.bind("<Button-1>", self.callback)
        master.mainloop()

    def callback(self, event):
        # get the clicked button
        clicked_btn = event.widget
        btn_at_row_col = clicked_btn.config(bg='blue', state='disabled')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Game(root)
```

The output GUI:

This will render a `10x10` grid of buttons.

[image]

Then you can click on any button which makes it blue.

[image]

Comment: big thanks, yes the callback function is what I have looked for.