# How to make buttons out of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scripting

I am trying to write a code that will make buttons out of Images. Whenever you click that a button It will display that image.

```
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
folder_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Teknoloji\Desktop\Phyton\Jack\Selam")

def Imagen():

    image = tkinter.Canvas(root,width=300,height=300)
    for b in folder_list:
        if b == my_text:
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f"Images\{b}"))
    label = tkinter.Label(image=img)
    print(my_text)
    label.image = img
    image.create_image(120,120,image=img)
    image.pack()

for i in folder_list:
    button = tkinter.Button(root,text=i,command=Imagen)
    my_text = button.cget("text")
    print(my_text)
    button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `my_text` and `b` are the same thing i guess, so whats the use of `if`, i recommend passing a parameter here onto `Imagen()`, like the path of the image, then open that path?

Comment: Why the path used in `listdir()` does not match with that in `Image.open()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have took your code and made some changes here:

```
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
folder_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Teknoloji\Desktop\Phyton\Jack\Selam")

def Imagen(img_path):
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f'images/{img_path}'))
    #label = tkinter.Label(image=img)
    image.whatever = img #keeping a reference, can be anything
    image.itemconfigure('image',image=img)
    image.pack()

for i in folder_list:
    button = tkinter.Button(root,text=i,command=lambda i=i:Imagen(i),width=10) 
    button.pack(pady=5)

image = tkinter.Canvas(root,width=300,height=300)
image.create_image(120,120,tag='image')

root.mainloop()
```

**What all have I done?**

- I've removed some unwanted part from your code, like unnecessary looping inside of function and also it seems like your not using your label to display image instead using `canvas`, either way ive made sure that it does not overwrite the existing image, when you press button.
- Also I have passed the image path as a parameter onto the function which opens the image, so that `lambda` can have a parameter to pass on to the function.

**How does the loop button work?**
(Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments))

> This may look magical, but here's what's happening. When you use that lambda to define your function, the open_this call doesn't get the value of the variable i at the time you define the function. Instead, it makes a closure, which is sort of like a note to itself saying "I should look for what the value of the variable i is at the time that I am called". Of course, the function is called after the loop is over, so at that time i will always be equal to the last value from the loop.
> Using the i=i trick causes your function to store the current value of i at the time your lambda is defined, instead of waiting to look up the value of i later.
> Do let me know if this works.

Do let me know if you have any doubts or error regarding this.

Cheers