# How to determine which button is clicked in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a software but the problem is when I click the  button in below code it always shows 9 as output. can anyone
suggest solution for this.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)

def click(i):
  print(i)

for i in range(10):
    btn = Button(frame,text="Button",command=lambda: click(i))
    btn.pack(...)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a partial object:

```
from functools import partial

for i in range(10):
    btn = Button(frame,text="Button",command=partial(click, i))
```

Or a lambda function default value:

```
for i in range(10):
    btn = Button(frame,text="Button",command=lambda i=i: click(i))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I think the OP needs to know why his "obvious" bindings don't work as expected.  I don't have the link right now though.