# Declare buttons in a loop in Tkinter (Python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, user-interface, tkinter

I have never created a GUI before and I decided to try to create one in Python3, using tkinter.

I would like to create a 5x5 "matrix" of buttons that change color and text when pressed. After some googling, I figure out how to do it for a single button and in principle I could just copy-paste and create the 25 buttons I need. However I'd like to find a more elegant way to do it inside a loop. My problem is that I need to give different names to each button, but I don't know how to do that.

I hope the question is clear enough. Thank you in advance for any help!!

Comment: You dont have to give different names, make a list of colors, and then loop through the colors.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)

Comment: @CoolCloud Mmmh you mean that whenever I click a specific button I could just update the color list? I will try to implement this idea

Comment: @JacksonPro oh, great! I haven't seen it! thanks a lot

Comment: @CoolCloud that would be awesome!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example on how to do so, by making a list of all the 25 color and then using the conventional matrix looping and assigning items to the buttons, like:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

colors = ['Red','Orange','Yellow','Green','Blue','Purple','Brown','Magenta',
        'Tan','Cyan','Olive','Maroon','Navy','Aquamarine','Turquoise','Silver',
        'Lime','Teal','Indigo','Violet','Pink','Black','White','Gray','crimson']
colors = list(reversed(colors)) # Reversing list bc pop returns last item

def color_changer(btn,color):
    btn.config(fg=color) # Change the color of the corresponding button

for i in range(5): # Number of rows
    for j in range(5): # Number of column
        color = colors.pop()  # First color
        btn = Button(root,text=color,fg='black',width=25)
        btn.grid(row=i,column=j) # Place the widget
        btn['command'] = lambda btn=btn,color=color: color_changer(btn,color) # Assign a command

root.mainloop()
```

There is a caveat here, you should define exactly 25 colors, else, you should use `try` to catch the `IndexError` that comes up and ignore it.

**How does the function work?:**
You are using `lambda` to create a new *nameless* function that takes in `btn` and `color` and passes that `btn` and `color` to the `color_changer()`. This way we can store corresponding `btn` and `color`, unlike if you would normally assign it like `lambda: color_changer(btn,color)`, it is just going to pass the last popped item. This is usually how we assign commands for buttons inside a loop.

**Alternative(to `lambda`):**
You can also use a nested function(avoiding `lambdas`). So the function would be like:

```
def nester(btn,color):
    def color_changer():
        btn.config(fg=color)
    return color_changer
```

and the command would be like:

```
btn['command'] = nester(btn,color)
```

This is similar to what `functools.partial` does.

Comment: A last question: is there a way to make the color change immediately? I noticed that it changed only after the pointer moves away from the pressed button.

Comment: @Onil90 The color changes only if you press the button, as your question states, "_I would like to create a 5x5 "matrix" of buttons that change color and text when pressed._".

Comment: Yes, that's right! And it does work fine. However I wonder why I can see the color only after the pointer leaves the button.

Comment: @Onil90 That's weird, by no means shall the code pasted here do that. It will ONLY change color if you click on it.