# tkinter buttons through a loop, how do i identify which was clicked?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8

I created a loop to create a button for each element in a list. How do I identify which button is clicked and then assign a command to each one, which will create a new page with the same name as the button clicked?.

```
       yvalue = 200
    for i in sdecks:
        deckbutton1=Button(fcpage,text=i,width=21,bd=2,fg="ghost white",bg="orchid1")
        deckbutton1.place(x=105, y=yvalue)
        yvalue = yvalue + 20
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)

Comment: No because I don't use a lambda in my code. But thanks!

Comment: You will need to use `lambda` or `functools.partial` or something similar. Why are you against using `lambda`?

Comment: I'm not against lambda at all, I just have no clue how to use it.

Comment: To use tkinter buttons effectively you need to know how to use lambda functions. This is a good tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either I don't get you question or this (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865156/11106801)) should answer your question:

```py
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk


def create_new_page(name_of_page):
    print("Creating new page with name=\"%s\"" % name_of_page)


root = tk.Tk()

for i in range(5):
    # Create the command using partial
    command = partial(create_new_page, i)

    button = tk.Button(root, text="Button number"+str(i+1), command=command)
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```