# Python: How can i get the selected element in a menu of menubar?

Tags: python, tkinter

So i was just improving the text editor that i made..
The problem is that i want to get the clicked element of the menu inside my menubar of tkinter window..

[image]

Here in this picture How can i get the clicked item "C++ Compile"?
I am just unable to figure out how to solve this..

Menu code:

```
Menubar = Menu(root, activebackground ="#0084FF", activeforeground = "#FFFFFF",bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#0084FF" ,font = "consolas")

Filemenu = Menu(root, tearoff = 0)
Filemenu.add_command(label="New",command=newTab)
Filemenu.add_separator()
Filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
Filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
Filemenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=saveAsFile)
Filemenu.add_separator()
Filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=deltab)
Filemenu.add_separator()
Filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
Menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=Filemenu)

toolsMenu = Menu(root,tearoff=0)
confmenu = Menu(root,tearoff=0)
runmenu = Menu(root,tearoff = 0)
runmenu.add_command(label = "Open file from cmd", command = lambda:runfile())
runmenu.add_separator()
runner_command = StringVar()
if isConf:
    for i in getConfs():
        runmenu.add_command(label = i, command = lambda:runnerConf(i))
    runmenu.add_separator()
runmenu.add_command(label= "New Runner",command = lambda:newrunner())
toolsMenu.add_cascade(label = "Runner", menu = runmenu)
toolsMenu.add_command(label = "Open cmd here", command = lambda:opencmd())
Menubar.add_cascade(label="Tools",menu = toolsMenu)
```

```
SPECS:
OS: Windows 7 (i will upgrade to Windows 20 ONLY)
Python: 3.8.10
Arch: x86 (32 bit)
```

Comment: Can you please show your code including the menus

Comment: @PCM okay but the whole code is 200 lines plus so only menus..

Comment: @PCM is it fine now? or more?

Comment: Where is the line for the C++ Compile ...

Comment: for that it reads a configuration file

Comment: What do you mean by 'get the clicked item'. You can write a command for that right?

Comment: @PCM I just can't figure that out...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234222/discussion-between-whirlpool-programmer-and-pcm).

Comment: Instead of `command = lambda:runnerConf(i)` use `command = lambda i=i: runnerConf(i)`

Answer (score 0):

As @TheLizzard has commented, the fix was just to use `command = lambda i=i: runnerConf(i)` instead of `command = lambda:runnerConf(i)`

Comment: If you want an explanation, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)