# Is there a way to import modules that are then executed only when some GUI event occurs?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a sort of OmniCode Tkinter app for all my beginner python programs.
All it does is look in my beginner-code file and produce a list of modules (just the string names for now) to be imported (using `importlib.import_module()`) and executed at the press of a Tkinter button.

Two problems I'm having now are that iteratively creating and passing `command=` *`kwargs`* to each button results in **all** the buttons executing only the last module in the aforementioned list.

The second problem is that interacting with this last module (if I understand the errors correctly) is impossible further than the initial `"Hello! this programme does xyz"` console response. It appears that **after importing the module and executing**, **it is immediately closed**, thus preventing any further interaction.

Here is my code:

```
Applications = [filename for filename in
                    os.listdir('C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/Gui Test')
                        if isfile(filename)]


def OpenApp(app):
    importlib.import_module(app)


def App_Buttons(_root):
    i = 0
    for app in Applications:
        tk.Button(_root,
                  # width=15,
                  height=2,
                  relief='solid',
                  borderwidth=1,
                  text=str(app),
                  command=lambda: OpenApp(app),
                  font=("Century Gothic", 16),
                  ).grid(row=4 + i,
                         column=0,
                         padx=20,
                         pady=15)
        tk.Label(_root,
                 text=f'This is the description of App Name: {str(app)}',
                 font=("Century Gothic", 16)
                 ).grid(row=4 + i,
                        column=1,
                        sticky='w')
        i += 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)

Comment: @TheLizzard It does solve the first problem, thank you! I still do get a Module Error, however: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Do it backwards.py'; 'Do it backwards' is not a package` , assuming 'Do it backwards' is a python script with no function definitions.

Comment: Is it in the correct directory? Also python files shouldn't have spaces or special characters in their names. Stick to whatever you can import using `import ...`

Comment: @TheLizzard Now I'm doubly confused. After refactoring the names of all the programmes to look more like: "DoItBackwards", the list of modules is empty. It only populated the list when the files were named with spaces.

Comment: @NathanNgqwebo you need to use `import module_name` as such for example `import DoltBackwards` and then you can access stuff in that module by `DoltBackwards.SomeClass()` or just do `from DoltBackwards import SomeClass` to simply use as `SomeClass()`, you don't need to make any lists

Comment: But consider @Matiiss that by the end of this project I'll likely have 30 such mini programmes, and for reusability, I would really like to find a solution that ensures that I only ever import (and keep open) modules that have been selected on the main app window.\ If I imported all the small programmes by hand, I would lose the automatic fineness, I would lose scalability, and I would miss out on a learning opportunity.

Comment: @NathanNgqwebo possibly then an easier approach may be to use `subprocess.Popen` to open the file as a new process (it requires the computer to have python installed tho), the other option is to convert each small program to an executable file and launch them like such

Comment: Executables sounds interesting. I'll get working. Thank you @Matiiss!