# How to to properly use a checkbox to delete itself in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner in python, I used tkinter to build a to-do list program. But the problem is I don't understand how it works.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def insert_Task(name):
    name = Checkbutton(root, text=name, command= lambda: del_task(name))
    name.pack()
    
def del_task(name):
    name.destroy()
    
insert_Entry = Entry(root)
insert_Button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda: insert_Task(insert_Entry.get()))

insert_Entry.pack()
insert_Button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The only way this should work is when name is passed into text, it is `insert_Entry.get()` and when the function is called it is the `Checkbutton` object.

Can someone explain to me if this is the case?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying your code works, you just don't know how — correct?

Comment: I don't 100% get your question but if your question is: why is `del_task` called with a `Checkbutton` object instead of a `str` object, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865170/11106801).

Comment: Yes, I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`lambda`s are used to create anonymous functions. The code:

```
command=lambda: insert_Task(insert_Entry.get())
```

Can also be written as:

```
def click_next(): #=== any name
    insert_Task(insert_Entry.get())

insert_Button=Button(....,command = click_next)
```

Why do we use `lambda` to pass arguments?
We need to pass the reference of the function, i.e without providing a `()`. Or else, the function is executed right away and the **returned** value is set as the command.

When you click on the button, `insert_Entry.get()` returns all the text which is entered in  `insert_Entry`. This is passed as the argument in `insert_Task` where a Check button is created with that name.

Similarly:

```
name = Checkbutton(root, text=name, command= lambda: del_task(name))
```

in this, a reference of the `Checkbutton` is passed as an argument to `del_task` so that on clicking on it, the method in invoked and the selected check button is destroyed

Comment: So, basically when lambda are used, the argument inside del_task function is referring to the Checkbox itself and when lambda is not used it is referring to the value inside of insert_Entry.