# I have a scrollbar Buttons here and I want to ask how can I get a specific output when I press a specific button

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def EditItem(product):
   print(product)

editbase = Tk()
editbase.title("Edit Item")
editbase.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

main_frame = Frame(editbase)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))

second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
```

This is where I'm troubled.

```
text_file = open('Cashier.txt') # I know it's better to use [with open()]
productname = []
counter = 0
for line in text_file:
  print(counter)
  line = line.strip('\n')
  product = line.split("=")
  productname.append(product[0])
  productprice = product[1]
  Button(second_frame, text=productname[counter], width=35, height=2, font=('Arial', 13, 'bold'), 
  command = lambda: EditItem(productname[counter])).grid(
                            row=counter, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
  counter += 1
counter = 0

exitbutton = Button(editbase, text="Exit", font=('Arial', 12), width=20, command=editbase.destroy)
exitbutton.pack(pady=10)

editbase.mainloop()
```

when you open this code there will be rows of product button names for example

Milk

Coffee

Chocolate

I want to make it so that when I press the Coffee Button then the product in the `EditItem` will be Coffee and not Milk because the counter after the `for` loop will always be 0 and it seems that the button will not pass down its current counter. And so the command will pass `EditItem(productname[0])` instead of the `EditItem(productname[currentcounter #Example only]`.

I also can't make an individual button because the amount of product is dynamic.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre]. I also see nothing related to a scrollbar in it now.

Comment: @martineau It is updated.

Comment: Sorry, that's still not runnable — which means complete enough that someone else can copy and paste the code on their own machine and execute it. For a tkinter program that implies there will be a call to `mainloop()` somewhere in it, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to [closure](https://zetcode.com/python/python-closures/) which means that a reference to the value of the variable `counter` is what's getting used by your `lambda` callback function and that value will always be the final value of the variable at the end of the `for` loop when it finishes executing.

The usual way to avoid the issue is to assign a ***default value*** to the function argument which will "capture" the variable's value *at the time the function is created*. The code below shows how to do that in the `for` loop at the end of your code.

Note I have also streamlined a few other things I noticed being done inefficiently / awkwardly in the block.

```
...

with open('Cashier.txt') as text_file:
    productname = []
    for counter, line in enumerate(text_file):
      print(counter)
      line = line.strip('\n')
      product = line.split("=")
      productname.append(product[0])
      productprice = product[1]
      Button(second_frame, text=productname[counter], width=35, height=2,
             font=('Arial', 13, 'bold'),
             command=lambda counter=counter:  # NOTE DEFAULT ARGUMENT VALUE ADDED.
                EditItem(productname[counter])).grid(row=counter, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

exitbutton = Button(editbase, text="Exit", font=('Arial', 12), width=20,
                    command=editbase.destroy)
exitbutton.pack(pady=10)
editbase.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer! Sorry, this was just a redundant question.
Here's the answer
[tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)

lambda i = counter: EditItem(productname[i])