# Non-repetitive way of passing a large set of parameters as a single object?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning how to use `tkinter`, and some example code to create a bunch of buttons for a calculator is used. It seems very bulky and repetitive, so I was wondering if there was a way to assign some or all of the parameters to a single object and just modify and pass that each time?

```
button1 = Button(gui, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(1), height=1, width=7)
button1.grid(row=2, column=0)

button2 = Button(gui, text=' 2 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(2), height=1, width=7)
button2.grid(row=2, column=1)

button3 = Button(gui, text=' 3 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(3), height=1, width=7)
button3.grid(row=2, column=2)

button4 = Button(gui, text=' 4 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(4), height=1, width=7)
button4.grid(row=3, column=0)

button5 = Button(gui, text=' 5 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(5), height=1, width=7)
button5.grid(row=3, column=1)

button6 = Button(gui, text=' 6 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(6), height=1, width=7)
button6.grid(row=3, column=2)

button7 = Button(gui, text=' 7 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(7), height=1, width=7)
button7.grid(row=4, column=0)

button8 = Button(gui, text=' 8 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(8), height=1, width=7)
button8.grid(row=4, column=1)

button9 = Button(gui, text=' 9 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(9), height=1, width=7)
button9.grid(row=4, column=2)

button0 = Button(gui, text=' 0 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                command=lambda: press(0), height=1, width=7)
button0.grid(row=5, column=0)
```

Comment: Do you know about lists and for-loops?

Comment: Try taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865116/16775594).

Answer (score 1):

In order to to keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and avoid repeating yourself— which is essentially what you're asking I think — you need to create the `Button`s in a loop. However [dynamically creating Python variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) is generally ***not a good idea***, so they should instead be put in some kind of container, like a `list`, rather than trying to give each of them individual names.

I'm not sure exactly if that is what you meant by "assign some or all of the parameters to a single object" because `tkinter` it could also mean grouping the widget together in some kind of GUI container. `tkinter` has something called a [`Frame`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/frame.html) widget for that sort of thing which allows them to be treated as a group.

The sample code below does both — it creates a `buttons` list *and* a `button_frame`:

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP 8 suggests avoiding `import *`.

NUM_BUTTONS = 10
BUTTONS_PER_ROW = 3

gui = tk.Tk()

def press(digit):
    gui.bell()

button_frame = tk.Frame(gui)  # Parent frame to hold all button widgets.
button_frame.pack()

buttons = []  # List of button widgets.
start_row = 2
for i in range(NUM_BUTTONS):
    row, col = divmod(i, BUTTONS_PER_ROW)
    value = (i+1) % NUM_BUTTONS
    button = tk.Button(button_frame, text=f'{value}', fg='black', bg='red',
                       command=lambda digit=value: press(digit), height=1, width=7)
    button.grid(row=start_row+row, column=col)
    buttons.append(button)  # Add widget to list.

gui.mainloop()
```

Here's the on-screen result:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You forgot to store the created buttons into the list `buttons`.

Comment: @acw1668: Thanks for pointing that out. Coincidentally I was already here fixing a different bug I noticed myself.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you use `:2d` to format the single digit value? Since you have used `width=7`, the formatting is not necessary.

Comment: @acw1668: I was thinking I needed to do it because the default justification of button text is `tk.CENTER`, but realized after your comment that it doesn't matter — so have removed it.