# Python - best way to capture current variables in lambda (rather than update the current one)?

Tags: python, lambda

This code demonstrates the problem well:

```
ans = []
for  x in range(1,10):
    ans.append(lambda: x)
# -----------------------
# now see what happened:
ans[0]()
# prints 9, but should print 1
```

What is the best way to have x be captured immediately in the function, rather than updating with the variable x later?

Comment: *why* do you want to do this? What is the problem, and what are you trying to solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments is an example of a common need for this, with a couple of solutions given.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
ans = []
for  x in range(1,10):
    ans.append(lambda *,x=x: x)
```

FYI x is declared as a global variable cuz python = dumb LOL!

Comment: but *why* did you come up with it? e.g. what is the point of having a list with seemingly useless lambdas in it?

Comment: glad you emphasized the word why, i wouldn't have known what u were asking for otherwise

Comment: x is not a global variable, so perhaps what is being said is dumb, rather than python itself for example.

Comment: is there a way to make x local to the for loop?

Comment: another thing is in case of `for x in range(0, 0)` - then `x` will never be defined, as loop doesn’t run.

Comment: that's true! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).