# create labels in a for loop that have an individual command

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a column of label containing images in a for loop, I want them to have a specific command when I do a right click a left click on the image, I searched a solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments) question. The answer of BrenBarn worked well only if i use a button. But the event Button-1, isn't returning any value that can differentiate one label from another.

**WORKING :**

```
active="red"
default_color="white"

def main(height=5,width=5):
  for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
      btn = tkinter.Button(frame, bg=default_color)
      btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=N+S+E+W)
      btn["command"] = lambda btn=btn: click(btn)

  for x in range(width):
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)

  for y in range(height):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)

  return frame

def click(button):
    print(button)
    if(button["bg"] == active):
        button["bg"] = default_color
    else:
        button["bg"] = active

w= main(10,10)
```

**NOT WORKING :**

```
active="red"
default_color="white"

def main(height=5,width=5):
  for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
      btn = tkinter.Button(frame, bg=default_color)
      btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=N+S+E+W)
      btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda btn=btn: click(btn))

  for x in range(width):
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)

  for y in range(height):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)

  return frame

def click(button):
    print(button)
    if(button["bg"] == active):
        button["bg"] = default_color
    else:
        button["bg"] = active

w= main(10,10)
```

Comment: The concept is the same, no matters it is for `command` option of `<Button-1>` event binding.

Comment: but when I do the same it's not working

Comment: The function for event binding requires an event argument: `lambda e, btn=btn: click(btn)`.

Comment: But for your case, `btn` argument is not necessary as the first event argument already has an attribute `widget` which is the widget that triggers the event: `lambda e: click(e.widget)`.

Answer (score 0):

The signatures of the functions required for `command` option of a button and event binding are different. Function for `command` option expects no argument, whereas function for event binding expects an argument, the `Event` object.

Therefore the following line:

```py
btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda btn=btn: click(btn))
```

should be as below:

```py
# added the required argument "e"
btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, btn=btn: click(btn))
```

However, for your case the `btn` argument is not necessary because the `Event` object has an attribute `widget` which is the widget that triggers the event:

```py
# used e.widget
btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: click(e.widget))
```