# create labels in a for loop that have an individual commande

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to create a column of label containing images in a for loop, I want them to have a specific command when I do a right click a left click on the image, I searched a solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments) question. The answer of BrenBarn worked well only if i use a button. But the event Button-1, isn't returning any value that can differentiate one label from another.

**WORKING :**

```
active="red"
default_color="white"

def main(height=5,width=5):
  for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
      btn = tkinter.Button(frame, bg=default_color)
      btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=N+S+E+W)
      btn["command"] = lambda btn=btn: click(btn)

  for x in range(width):
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)

  for y in range(height):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)

  return frame

def click(button):
    print(button)
    if(button["bg"] == active):
        button["bg"] = default_color
    else:
        button["bg"] = active

w= main(10,10)
```

**NOT WORKING :**

```
active="red"
default_color="white"

def main(height=5,width=5):
  for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
      btn = tkinter.Button(frame, bg=default_color)
      btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=N+S+E+W)
      btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda btn=btn: click(btn))

  for x in range(width):
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame, x, weight=1)

  for y in range(height):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, y, weight=1)

  return frame

def click(button):
    print(button)
    if(button["bg"] == active):
        button["bg"] = default_color
    else:
        button["bg"] = active

w= main(10,10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda btn=btn: click(btn))
```

You're creating an anonymous function that takes a single argument. You call this argument `btn`. When tkinter calls the function via a binding it automatically calls the function with one argument representing the event. So, when the function is called because of the `<Button-1>` event, `btn` is set to the event object, overriding the default value.

You need to define your `lambda` function to accept this event parameter in addition to any other arguments. One way to do it is like this:

```
btn.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, btn=btn: click(btn))
```

With this, the `lambda` function receives the event parameter and also defines a default value for `btn` which is then passed to the `click` function.

**However**, if you're using `bind` rather than setting the `command` attribute of the button, there's no need to pass in the button itself. The widget is one of the attributes of the event object.

You can redefine your function to accept the event and use the `widget` parameter like so:

```
def click(event):
    button = event.widget
    print("Button:", button)
    if(button["bg"] == active):
        button["bg"] = default_color
    else:
        button["bg"] = active
```

You would then define the button like so:

```
btn.bind("<Button-1>", click)
```

Comment: Holy cow, It worked I Thank you so much for the answer, you're the best.