# Using tkinter to create a button using a variable in a loop but variable attached to button is only variable from final iteration of loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want each button to be attached to it's variable from whatever iteration of the loop that button was made in.

```
    def clicked():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    label=Label(root,text=('clicked'+str(Char1.name)))
    label.grid()

    nameButton = Button(root, text=Char1.name, command=(clicked))
    nameButton.grid()
    ageLabel = Label(root, text=Char1.age)
    ageLabel.grid(column = columnNo, row = rowNo)
    speedLabel = Label(root, text=Char1.speed)
    speedLabel.grid(column = columnNo+1, row = rowNo)
    hpLabel = Label(root, text=Char1.hp)
    hpLabel.grid(column = columnNo+2, row = rowNo)
```

After each iteartion of the loop, the Char1 variable is updated with new information. How do I get the information from the Char1 variable to be stored so when the button is pressed it outputs "clicked "+whichever button was actaully pressed. At the moment, it doesn't matter which button I press, the output is always "clicked "+whatever the name of the Char1 variable was in the final iteration of the loop.
No clue if Iv'e explained that well enough but I hope someone can figure out what I mean.

Here's the full code for reference (copy and pasting messed up the indents also I know it's super messy I haven't got rid of the code from before I started trying to put it into a gui)

```
import random as r
import os.path
from send2trash import send2trash
from tkinter import *
import time as t

savePath=('C:/Users/sarah/Documents/python/character generator/characters')
characters = []
rowNo=0

root = Tk()
root.title("Character Generator")
root.geometry('1000x500')


for f in os.listdir(savePath):
    os.remove(os.path.join(savePath, f))

class Char:
    def __init__(self, name, age, speed, hp):
    self.name=name
    self.age=age
    self.speed=speed
    self.hp=hp
        
def CharDef():
    global Char1, Char, rowNo

    #Defining local variables
    speedMin=1
    speedMax=2
    ageMin=10
    ageMax=90
    hpMin=5
    hpMax=20
    columnNo=1


    #Calculating midpoints
    midpointSpeed = round((int(speedMin)+int(speedMax))/2)
    midpointAge = round((int(ageMin)+int(ageMax))/2)
    midpointHp = round(int(hpMin)+int(hpMax)/2)

    #name
    with open('names.txt','r') as f:
        allNames=f.read()
        names=list(map(str,allNames.split()))

    name=r.choice(names).capitalize()

    #age
    age=r.randint(ageMin,ageMax)

    #speed
    speed=r.randint(speedMin,speedMax)

    if int(round(speed,1)) < int(midpointSpeed):
        speed='slow'
    elif int(round(speed,1)) >= int(midpointSpeed):
        speed='fast'

    #health points
    hp=r.randint(hpMin,hpMax)
    if age > midpointAge and hp > hpMin:
        chance=r.randint(1,2)
        if chance == 1:
            hp=round(90%(hp))
            if hp <= 1:
                hp=hp+2
            
    Char1 = Char(name,age,speed,hp)

    #Is character fast?
    if Char1.speed == 'fast':
        IsFast = True
    elif Char1.speed == 'slow':
        IsFast = False

    #Is character fit?
    if Char1.hp >= midpointHp+-1:
        IsFit = True
    elif Char1.hp < midpointHp:
        IsFit = False

    #Is character a good age?
    if Char1.age <= midpointAge+-1:
        IsYoung = True
    elif Char1.age > midpointAge:
        IsYoung = False
    
    if IsFit == True and IsFast == True and IsYoung == True:
        best = '**'
    else:
        best=' '
    print(best+" "+Char1.name+" "+best)
    print(" Age: "+str(Char1.age))
    print(" Speed: "+Char1.speed.capitalize())
    print(" Health Points: "+str(Char1.hp)+"/"+str(hpMax))
    print()
    print("--")
    print()

    #Writing to tkinter window

    def clicked():
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        label=Label(root,text=('clicked'+str(Char1.name)))
        label.grid()
    
    nameButton = Button(root, text=Char1.name, command=(clicked))
    nameButton.grid()
    ageLabel = Label(root, text=Char1.age)
    ageLabel.grid(column = columnNo, row = rowNo)
    speedLabel = Label(root, text=Char1.speed)
    speedLabel.grid(column = columnNo+1, row = rowNo)
    hpLabel = Label(root, text=Char1.hp)
    hpLabel.grid(column = columnNo+2, row = rowNo)




times=0
while times != 3:
    CharDef()
    fileName = (str(Char1.name))
    fileNameComplete=os.path.join(savePath, fileName+".txt") 
    f=open(fileNameComplete,'w')
    f.write(str(Char1.name.capitalize())+'\n')
    f.write(str(Char1.age)+'\n')
    f.write(str(Char1.speed)+'\n')
    f.write(str(Char1.hp)+'\n')
    times+=1
    rowNo+=1
f.close()
root.mainloop()

files = os. listdir(savePath)
for file in files: 
    fileName = file.replace('.txt', "")
    characters.append(fileName)

while True:
    choice=input("Which character will you pick? ").capitalize()
    if choice in characters:
        break
    elif choice not in characters:
        print("invalid")
    
print()

fileName=os.path.join(savePath, choice+".txt")
with open(fileName,'r') as f:
    allInfo=f.read()
    info=list(map(str,allInfo.split()))

Char = Char(info[0],info[1],info[2],info[3])

print(Char.name+", "+str(Char.age)+", "+str(Char.speed)+", "+str(Char.hp))
```

Comment: Almost certainly related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments Would be helpful if you could share an executable and complete version of your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)