# Wanna handle click event on buttons made using loop

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I used for loop to create buttons in tkinter. And wanna apply an event on all the created button. Event is like, when I click on button its bg color should change and won't back to normal until I click back on it. But in my code color of last button is changing only.

```
def button_Clicked(e):
    bij['bg'] = 'red'
for i in range (0,8):
    for j in range (0,8):
        bij = tk.Button(compFrame, width = 10, height=4)
        bij.grid(row = i, column = j, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        bij.bind("<Button-1>", button_Clicked)
```

Is there any way that I can connect all the buttons with event that if I clicked on any button then only its color should change not of the last one or any others.

Comment: Is this really how your code is indented? You're only calling `bind` on the last button that was created.

Comment: that was my mistake, bind command was inside the loop

Comment: Then please update the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer:

As @Thingamabobs pointed out, it's possible to get the button via `e.widget` in `button_Clicked` function via the event object `e`. Thus, it's not necessary to pass the button object to the function.

```
def button_Clicked(e):
    button = e.widget

    # toggle between 'red' and default color
    if button['bg'] != 'red':
        button['bg'] = 'red'
    else:
        button['bg'] = 'SystemButtonFace'


for i in range(0, 8):
    for j in range(0, 8):
        bij = tk.Button(compFrame, width=10, height=4)
        bij.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=5, pady=5)
        bij.bind("<Button-1>", button_Clicked)

root.mainloop()
```

### Old Answer:

1. You need to bind the event inside the loop. Right now, `bij` is outside the loop, so it's only the last button.
2. To make sure the event changes color for the correct button, you need to add an argument to `button_Clicked`
3. To change toggle the background color on each click, it's necessary to add a condition in `button_Clicked`

```
def button_Clicked(e, button):
    # toggle between 'red' and default color
    if button['bg'] != 'red':
        button['bg'] = 'red'
    else:
        button['bg'] = 'SystemButtonFace'
for i in range (0,8):
    for j in range (0,8):
        bij = tk.Button(compFrame, width = 10, height=4)
        bij.grid(row = i, column = j, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        bij.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, bij=bij: button_Clicked(event, bij))
```

As @BryanOakley rightly point out, it's necessary to use the trick

```
lambda event, bij=bij: button_Clicked(event, bij)
```

to make sure the lambda closure uses the current `bij` value in the loop.

Alternatively, it's possibly cleaner to use `functools.partial` for the last line

```
from functools import partial

...
        bij.bind("<Button-1>", partial(button_Clicked, button=bij))
```

Comment: But still it is not working. only changing color of last button.

Comment: You're making a very common mistake. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I got it now.

Comment: @BryanOakley well caught, answer updated. It's tested and working now.

Comment: @MDDANISH if someone took the time to help you out, it is good practice to *reward* them by [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) their answers. We feel valued helping you gain progress. All of your questions have no accepted answers. You may reread those answers too.

Comment: @Tim parsing the button through is kind of redundant, since you could just do `e.widget` to get the button.