# PYTHON TKINTER - How to make a button which returns its text when clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

In Python Tkinter, I am trying to make a button which returns its text when clicked.
I am making multiple buttons so a for loop will be used.

This is so far what I have come up with:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for i in range(len(lst)): 
    Button(window, text = lst[i], command = lambda : print(lst[i]))
```

The problem with this code is, when I click on the buttons, it will only print the last element from lst.

Please can someone help me out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments

Comment: I found a solution.