# How to assign command for a button in range tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, range

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.config(bg = "white")

list = ["a", "b", "c"]

for i in list:
    Button(root, text = i,command = i).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

After running this program, I get the command of every button as "c". But I need each buttons command as each element of list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments

Comment: The obvious problem that remains is that `"c"` is a string, not a function.

Comment: Why do you assign a string to the `command` option of a button? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I don't think it is a duplicate of the linked question because OP does not reference `i` inside a `lambda`.  It just assign a string to the `command` option and it will not produce the issue mentioned in the question and the linked question.

Comment: BTW `list` is a builtin and should not be used as a variable name.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the user clicks any of the buttons? All we can do is guess.

Comment: @acw1668 I assumed that was a typo as no "real" function is mentioned, prolly the OP missed out on it