# Apache Airflow : create tasks using for loop in one dag, I want tasks made of for loop to respond to each xcom

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

A task that performs the same task in one dag was created using a for loop. It is hoped to be divided into two branches that depend on the result of this task. However, all tasks created using the for loop return the xcom of the last task. How can tasks created using for loop return each xcom?

Each task a,b,c returns xcom_a, xcom_b, and xcom_c. However, branch tasks all get the same xcom_c. What should I do?

```
default_args ={'start_date':days_ago(1)}
dag=DAG(
    dag_id='batch_test',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None)

def count(**context):
    name = context['params']['name']
    dict = {'a':50,
        'b':100,
        'c':150}
    if dict[name]<100:
        task_id=f'add_{name}'
        return task_id
    elif dict[name]>=100:
        task_id=f'times_{name}'
        return task_id
def branch(**context):
    task_id = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=f'count_task_{name}')
    return task_id
def add(**context):
    ans = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=f'branch_task_{name}')
    ans_dict = {'add_a':50+100,
                'add_b':100+100,
                'add_c':150+100}
    ans = ans_dict[ans]
    return print(ans)
def times(**context):
    ans = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=f'branch_task_{name}')
    ans_dict = {'times_a':50*100,
            'times_b':100*100,
            'times_c':150*100}
    ans = ans_dict[ans]
    return print(ans)

name_list = ['a','b','c']
for name in name_list:
    exec_count_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id = f'count_task_{name}',
            python_callable = count,
            provide_context=True,
        params = {'name':name},
        dag=dag
        )
    exec_branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id = f'branch_task_{name}',
        python_callable = branch,
        provide_context = True,
        dag = dag
        )
    exec_add_count = PythonOperator(
        task_id = f'add_{name}',
        python_callable = add,
        provide_context = True,
        dag = dag
        )
    exec_times_count = PythonOperator(
        task_id = f'times_{name}',
        python_callable = times,
        provide_context = True,
        dag = dag
        )

    exec_count_task >> exec_branch_task >> [exec_add_count, exec_times_count]
```

**i want this...**
task_a >> branch_a (branch python operator, xcom pull returned by **task_a**) >> [task_a1, task_a2]
task_b >> branch_b (branch python operator, xcom pull returned by **task_b**) >> [task_b1, task_b2]
task_c (>> branch_c (branch python operator, xcom pull returned by **task_c**) >> [task_c1, task_c2]

**but**
task_a >> branch_a (branch python operator, xcom pull returned by **task_c**) >> [task_a1, task_a2]
task_b >> branch_b (branch python operator, xcom pull returned by **task_c**) >> [task_b1, task_b2]
task_c >> branch_c (branch python operator, xcom pull returned by **task_c**) >> [task_c1, task_c2]

Comment: Please show explicitly the arguments of the BranchPythonOperator.

Comment: @MatthiasHuschle I edited what I was going to do with a simple example. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe using classic operators and the TaskFlow API. If you are able to add more context and code of what you are *actually* executing that would be most helpful.

In the meantime, here are the examples I used should it give you some guidance for troubleshooting. I added a task at the end of the streams to check that the first task indeed pushes its expected value.

**Classic Operators**

```
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator, PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule


with DAG(dag_id="multiple_branch_loop", start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None):
    def xcom_push(val):
        return val

    def func():
        ...

    def choose(val):
        return f"task_{val}"

    def check_xcom_output_from_first(val, expected_val):
        assert val == expected_val

    stuff = ["a", "b", "c"]
    for i in stuff:
        first = PythonOperator(task_id=f"first_task_{i}", python_callable=xcom_push, op_kwargs={"val": i})
        branch = BranchPythonOperator(task_id=f"branch_{i}", python_callable=choose, op_kwargs={"val": i})
        second = PythonOperator(task_id=f"task_{i}", python_callable=func)
        third = PythonOperator(task_id=f"task_{i}a", python_callable=func)
        check = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"check_{i}",
            trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,
            python_callable=check_xcom_output_from_first,
            op_kwargs={"val": first.output, "expected_val": i},
        )

        first >> branch >> [second, third] >> check
```

The `check*` tasks succeed meaning the first task in a given stream does push its value and not the last stream's.
[image]

**TaskFlow API**

```py
from pendulum import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule


@dag(start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def multiple_branch_loop():
    @task()
    def xcom_push(val):
        return val

    @task()
    def func():
        ...

    @task.branch()
    def choose(val):
        return f"task_{val}"

    @task(trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE)
    def check_xcom_output_from_first(val, expected_val):
        assert val == expected_val

    stuff = ["a", "b", "c"]
    for i in stuff:
        first = xcom_push.override(task_id=f"first_task_{i}")(val=i)
        branch = choose.override(task_id=f"branch_{i}")(val=first)
        second = func.override(task_id=f"task_{i}")()
        third = func.override(task_id=f"task_{i}a")()
        check = check_xcom_output_from_first.override(task_id=f"check_{i}")(val=first, expected_val=i)

        first >> branch >> [second, third] >> check

multiple_branch_loop()
```

Same expected behavior as well confirmed in the `check*` tasks:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
However, the same problem still occurs. 
Each task_a, task_b and task_c returns xcom_a, xcom_b and xcom_c.
But branch tasks all get xcom_c...

Answer (score 4):

Your functions `branch`, `add`, and `times` don't define `name` themselves, so it is taken out of global context, which is at time of function execution the last value of `for name in name_list`. This is a common trap explained e.g. here: [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments)

To fix it, you can either pull `name` from `context` as in `count`, or provide it via `op_args` or `op_kwargs` when you create the respective operator, as in the answer by Josh Fell:

```
        first = PythonOperator(task_id=f"first_task_{i}", python_callable=xcom_push, op_kwargs={"val": i})
        branch = BranchPythonOperator(task_id=f"branch_{i}", python_callable=choose, op_kwargs={"val": i})
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a subtle trap. Another way is to pass name as argument to branch, add, times, so it doesn't take it from global context.