# How to dynamically focus on widgets under the mouse cursor?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building a tic-tac-toe gui with tkinter. Each cell is a Frame and I would like to be able to focus on any of them using the mouse.

Here is what I tried:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_event(event, target):
    target.focus()
    print(target)


class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.frames = []
        self.main = tk.Frame(self, bg = "black")
        self.build_widgets()
        self.main.pack()
        
    def build_widgets(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.frames.append([])
            for j in range(3):
                newframe = tk.Frame(self.main, bg='white', width=50, height=50,
                                    highlightcolor="blue", highlightthickness=1)
                self.frames[i].append(newframe)
                self.frames[i][j].bind("<Enter>", 
                                       lambda event : on_event(event, self.frames[i][j]))
                self.frames[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, padx = 1, pady = 1)


Example().mainloop()
```

This does detect the transition from one frame to another but for some reason it seems like it only remembers the last created frame (printed as `.!frame.!frame9`). Why is the bottom-right cell the only one to take focus?

I thought the reason was that i = j = 2 at the end of the loops so `target` is `self.frame[2][2]`  once the loops end but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to pass arguments to the function. The function is passed an object which can tell you which widget received the event.

First, change your binding to this:

```
self.frames[i][j].bind("<Enter>", on_event)
```

Next, change your function to this:

```
def on_event(event):
    event.widget.focus()
    print(event.widget)
```

---

If you need to create widgets in a loop, and pass arguments to a binding, see the answers to [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/)