# Grabbing Tkinter Button Text That Can Change

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm building an interface that loads buttons based upon text in a CSV file; the number of buttons, length of text, etc. can all be different. When a button is pressed, its text should be appended to a file.

I've greatly simplified my code/problem below, such that it creates buttons based upon elements in a list, and then appends selected button text to another list.

With either of the `tk.Button` lines, the line that is appended as chosen is always the last element in the `msgs` list (i.e., `'you say'`) rather than whatever button text was last selected.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(side = tk.TOP)

# the str in this list are read from a CSV (len changes)
msgs = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'i dont know why', 'you say']
chosen = []

for m in msgs: 
    # Both of the next two lines end up printing 'you say' to the terminal
    # regardless of which button is pressed

    #btn = tk.Button(frame, text=m, command=lambda: choose_msg(m))
    btn = tk.Button(frame, text=m, command=lambda: choose_msg(btn.cget('text')))
    btn.pack(side=tk.TOP) 

def choose_msg(msg):
    chosen.append(msg)
    print('test chosen: ', msg)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

[DeliriousEuphoria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13382000/delrius-euphoria) pointed out [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments) that essentially answers this one. The following line solves it:

`btn = tk.Button(frame, text=m, command=lambda m=m: choose_msg(m))`

The explanation is from @[brenbarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427416/brenbarn) on [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments):

> Change your lambda to lambda m=m: choose_msg(m).
>
> This may look magical, but here's what's happening. When you use that
> lambda to define your function, the open_this call doesn't get the
> value of the variable i at the time you define the function. Instead,
> it makes a closure, which is sort of like a note to itself saying "I
> should look for what the value of the variable i is at the time that I
> am called". Of course, the function is called after the loop is over,
> so at that time i will always be equal to the last value from the
> loop.
>
> Using the i=i trick causes your function to store the current value of
> i at the time your lambda is defined, instead of waiting to look up
> the value of i later.