# Tkinter. clear entry widget when clicked or in focus

Tags: python, tkinter, events, magento, tkinter-entry

I found similar questions but this one in particular.
I ve tried a few different ways but i can t make it work. Total noob with events!
I don t understand how to refer to the widget i guess...
The app simply connects to a database, and the for loop creates a label, an entry and a button for each column in the table which will allow to insert new lines in the database.
I want to default the entry widget with a 0, but i would like the 0 to clear as soon as the user clicks or focuses on the widget.

```py
def confirm_ad_table():
    global widget_list

    #Create connection
    conn = sqlite3.connect('home_finance_database - Copia')
    #Create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    def clear_zero(widget):
        if widget.get() == '0':
            widget.delete(0, END)
                      
    c.execute(f"PRAGMA table_info ({entry_ad_table.get()})")
    column_list = [column[1] for column in c.fetchall()]

    for widget in widget_list:
        widget.destroy()
    #In Chat GPT's words: "If you destroy the widget the list still contains them. You need to clear the list""
    widget_list = []

    for col in column_list:
        lab_widget = Label(tab2, text=col)
        entry_widget = Entry(tab2, width=35)
        btn_widget = Button(tab2, text="Submit")

        entry_widget.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda: clear_zero(entry_widget))
        entry_widget.bind("<Key>", lambda: clear_zero(entry_widget))    

        widget_list.append(lab_widget)
        widget_list.append(entry_widget)
        widget_list.append(btn_widget)
    


    for num, widget in enumerate(widget_list):
        if type(widget) == Label:
            widget.grid(row=num+2, column=0)
        elif type(widget) == Entry:
            widget.grid(row=num+1, column=1)
            widget.insert(0, "0")
        elif type(widget) == Button:
            widget.grid(row=num, column=2)


    #Commit changes
    conn.commit()
    #Close connection
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Please fix your questions syntax and add all the needed code for a running example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Change `lambda: clear_zero(entry_widget)` to `lambda entry_widget=entry_widget: clear_zero(entry_widget)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter creating buttons in for loop passing command arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments). It's not exactly the same problem but it's the same type

Comment: If you don’t use `lambda` to hide the automatic event parameter, you can use it to reference the entry widget without explicitly passing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind an event to a function, the function is automatically passed an object that represents the event. Within that event object you can get a reference to the widget via the `widget` attribute.

So, the first step is to define your function to accept this event object and use the `widget` attribute to access the entry widget that got the event:

```
def clear_zero(event):
    if event.widget.get() == '0':
        event.widget.delete(0, END)
```

Next, define your binding by removing the `lambda` and referencing the function directly:

```
entry_widget.bind("<FocusIn>", clear_zero)
entry_widget.bind("<Key>", clear_zero)
```