# PyQt generate Button-Connectors

Tags: python, button, pyqt, connect

I want to generate automatically the button-connections... but dont work:

```
    self._ = {}
    j = 0
    for i in self.btn:
        self._[i] = 'self._' + repr(j)
        print self._[i]
        self.button[i].clicked.connect(self._[i])
        j += 1
```

should bind the `button[i]` at the function `_j ( def _1(self): / def _2(self): / ...` but at execute:

```
connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'str'
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all, you need to pass a function or signal. Try to use `getattr`to get the function the string is representing.

Something like this may work

```
self.button[i].clicked.connect(getattr(self, '_'.format(j)))
```

Comment: What are the Prams of this function? the first is `self`, the second the `name of the function` but the third?

Comment: There is no third argument there.

Comment: I have: `self.button[i].clicked.connect(setattr(self, self._[i]))` And the error: `TypeError: setattr expected 3 arguments, got 2`

Comment: you wrote the wrong function, it should be getattr, not setattr. That was from the other answer. I made a edit now so reread the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an actual callable method instead of sending the string to `connect()`:

```
def make_slot(self, i):
    print 'clicked %i' % i 

self._ = {}
for i in self.btn:
    slot = self.make_slot(i)
    self._[i] = slot
    self.button[i].clicked.connect(slot)
```

(The make_slot function is to prevent python late-binding quirkiness, see [Creating functions in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop) about that)

Also, instead of building a dict, maybe you could add the slots directly to self:

```
setattr(self, 'on_button_%i_clicked' % i, slot) # perhaps more convenient?
```

That way, you could refer to them separately as `self.on_button_42_clicked` if you need too.