# Is it possible to make wrapper object for numbers, e.g. float, to make it mutable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability, mutable, shallow-copy

In Python 3 everything is supposed to be an object, even numbers, but they're **immutable**.

**Is it possible to create wrapper object for numbers, e.g. float, such that it would behave exactly as ordinary numbers except it must be mutable?**

I've wondered whether it would be feasible using built-in **type** function by creating anonymous wrapper object deriving from float, but changing it behaviour to be mutable.

```
>>> f = lambda x : type('', (float,), dict())(x)
>>> a = f(9)
>>> a
9.0
```

**What parameters must I change *f* to make number *a* be mutable?**

How I verify if a number is mutable:

I must be able to create such function *f* that would create from integer value a float value and after shallow copy it would behave in the following manner:

```
>>> list_1 = [f(i) for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> list_1
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
>>> list_2 = copy.copy(list_1)
>>> list_1[0] *= 100
>>> list_1
[100.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
>>> list_2
[100.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Modification of the first list, have changed both of them.

**Maybe I must add some fields to dict() or add additional base class that would enforce mutability?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values are immutable. They're platonic forms. An expression like `5 := 3` is nonsensical. What are mutable are `locations`, usually referred to as addresses or pointers. Python doesn't have those, but we can fake it by using a container type like a `list`, which is really a location that references other locations.

Here's a partial implementation of a mutable numerical type by using a `list` to store a location where we will keep the value of the number and change the value in that location when it should change, and because all copies of a mutable number will share that location, all copies will see the change

```
import copy

# Convenience to work with both normal and mutable numbers
def _get_value(obj):
    try:
        return obj.value[0]
    except:
        return obj

class mutable_number(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        # Mutable storage because `list` defines a location
        self.value = [value]

    # Define the comparison interface
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return _get_value(self) == _get_value(other)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return _get_value(self) != _get_value(other)

    # Define the numerical operator interface, returning new instances
    # of mutable_number
    def __add__(self, other):
        return mutable_number(self.value[0] + _get_value(other))

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return mutable_number(self.value[0] * _get_value(other))

    # In-place operations alter the shared location
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.value[0] += _get_value(other)
        return self

    def __imul__(self, other):
        self.value[0] *= _get_value(other)
        return self

    # Define the copy interface
    def __copy__(self):
        new = mutable_number(0)
        new.value = self.value
        return new

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value[0])

x = mutable_number(1)
y = copy.copy(x)
y *= 5
print x

list_1 = [mutable_number(i) for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]]
list_2 = copy.copy(list_1)
list_1[0] *= 100
print list_1
print list_2
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear, and I can add more documentation

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a wrapper like the following would be what you need.

```
# To solve scope issues. See
# <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop>
# for details.
def make_new_method(self, method_name):
    def new_method(self, *a, **aa):
        method = getattr(self._type, method_name)
        return method(self._heart, *a, **aa)
    return new_method


class Mutable():
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._heart = obj
        self._type = type(obj)

        # Remap each of the heart object's attributes to be used on the
        # wrapper object.
        for attr_name in dir(self._type):
            # Do not overwrite existing Mutable methods, only set new ones
            # from its heart.
            if attr_name not in dir(Mutable):
                # Methods need to be treated differently.
                if callable(getattr(self._type, attr_name)):
                    new_attr = make_new_method(self, attr_name)
                    setattr(Mutable, attr_name, new_attr)
                else:
                    attr_value = getattr(self._heart, attr_name)
                    setattr(self, attr_name, attr_value)

    def set(self, new_value):
        if self._type is type(new_value):
            self._heart = new_value
        else:
            self.__init__(new_value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Mutable({repr(self._heart)})'
```

When you write `mutable3 = Mutable(3)` it stores the value you want to be mutable (3, in this case) in the atribute `_heart` of an instance of the `Mutable` class and remaps its methods to be used directly with the instance itself. It allows, for example, doing

```
In [1]: a = list(map(Mutable, range(3)))

In [2]: a
Out[2]: [Mutable(0), Mutable(1), Mutable(2)]

In [3]: b = a[1]

In [4]: b.set('hello')

In [5]: a
Out[5]: [Mutable(0), Mutable('hello'), Mutable(2)]
```

It sounds to me like creating "symlinks" between variables, a behaviour we would achieve using pointers in a lower level language like C.