# lock external variable when define function in python

Tags: python

One of my function will use external variables, but the external variables will change when I use this function. Here is an example:

```
func_list=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    def func():
        print(i)
    func_list.append(func)
for j in range(0,6):
    func_list[j]()
```

I hope the output is [1,2,3,4,5,6], but the real output is [6,6,6,6,6,6]
I know one of solution is using closure, like this:

```
func_list=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    def create_func():
        nonlocal i
        number=i
        def func():
            print(number)
        return func
    func=create_func()
    func_list.append(func)
for j in range(0,6):
    func_list[j]()
```

This programs could output [1,2,3,4,5,6]. But it looks a bit ugly. It use additional 4, at least 3, lines to solve this problem...Is there some more simple methods/function decorations to solve this problem?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func_list=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    def func(i = i):
        print(i)
    func_list.append(func)

for j in range(0,6):
    func_list[j]()
```

It works because `i` is evaluated in the function definition and its *value* is put in as the default for the keyword argument, not the *variable*.

Of course, if you need to pass in a keyword argument called `i`, this will break down, in which case you probably want to use the (uglier) solution you gave.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want. Maybe it is the best solution.

Comment: @X.Li You could try [this much better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop#3431699). I found shortly it after answering this.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen that. That could be a good answer. But your answer is good enough for me.

Comment: @X.Li You can accept answers that worked for you by clicking the check mark below the vote buttons.

Comment: sorry for forgot accept answer. I have done just now. Thank you again.