# Binding many buttons to a function, passing each button's name as an argument

Tags: python, tkinter

Note that my problem is the opposite of this: [Creating functions in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop) in that I have many buttons and one function, not many functions.

I create 10 numbered buttons from a `for` loop, then try to bind each one to a function that will print the button's number; See code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        # creating buttons and adding them to dictionary

        self.buttons = {}
        for number in range(1, 11):
            self.buttons.update({'button' + str(number): tk.Button(self, height=1, width=4, bg="grey", text=number)})

        # example of a pair in the dictionary: 'button2': <Tkinter.Button instance at 0x101f9ce18>


        """ bind all the buttons to callback, each button is
            named something like 'button3',so I take the number off
            the end of its name and feed that as an argument to Callback"""

        for button in self.buttons:
            self.buttons[button].bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.Callback(event, button[6:]))
            self.buttons[button].pack(side='left')

    def Callback(self, event, num):
        print(num)
```

All the buttons appear on the window no problem, but when I click any of them, the console prints '`10`', as opposed to the button's number. It seems the function is only remembering the last argument it was given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First lets correct your code to give the desired answer.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.buttons = {}
        for number in range(1, 11):
            self.buttons.update({'button' + str(number): tk.Button(self, height=1, width=4, bg="grey", text=number)})

        for button in self.buttons:
            self.buttons[button].bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, num=button[6:]: self.Callback(event, num))
            self.buttons[button].pack(side='left')               #\____________/

    def Callback(self, event, num):
        print(num)

Window().mainloop()
```

---

**Explanation**:

The trick lies in the way lambda functions work.

When you write `lambda event: self.Callback(event, button[6:])`, it doesn't get the value of **`button[6:]`** at that instance and store it. Instead, it makes a *closure*, which is sort of like a note to itself saying "*I should look for what the value of the variable button(the iterator) is at the time that I am called*".

Now when the loop is over and every widget is ready and set up, and you call it, it will look for the value of *button* at that time, which is ofcourse the last value of the iteration (here, `button10`).

`num=button[6:]` causes the function to store the current value of the counter(here *button*) at the time your lambda is defined, instead of waiting to look up the value of *button* later.

Credits: [BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865116/tkinter-creating-buttons-in-for-loop-passing-command-arguments#10865170)

---

Just to add, you can do what you are doing right now in much less code using the `command` attribute of `Button` widget. Here is an example.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        for number in range(1, 11):
            tk.Button(self, height=1, width=4, bg="grey", text=number, command=lambda num=number: self.Callback(num)).pack(side='left')

    def Callback(self, num):
        print(num)

Window().mainloop()
```

Comment: Liked your add-on answer involving "much less code". Also on showing the use of `command=lambda num=number: self.Callback(num)`. Thumbs up. ;)