# Dynamically add support for arithmetic magic function in a python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Let say I have a python class `A`:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, matrix, metadata: list):
        self.matrix = np.array(matrix)
        self.metadata = metadata
    #...
```

Now I want all arithmetic operations work for my class. They supposed to simply translate the operation to `matrix`, i.e. like so:

```py
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            raise ValueError("Not allowed.")
        else:
            return A(
                matrix=self.matrix.__add__(other),
                metadata=self.metadata,
            )
```

Now the problem is that I have to repeate almost the same code for each arithmetic magic function, i.e `__add__, __sub__, __mul__, __truediv__, __pow__, __radd__, __rsub__, __rmul__, __rtruediv__, __iadd__, __isub__, __imul__, __itruediv__, __abs__, __round__, __floor__, __ceil__, __trunc__`. Which leads to a lot of repeating code.

**How can I define them dynamically in a for loop?** like

```py
magic_functions = ["__add__", "__sub__", ...]
for magic_function in magic_functions:
    # define the method and add it to the class
```

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop

Comment: I suggest to forget the loop, and explicitly define and test these matrix arithmetic methods: the next guy to read your code will thank you for it!

Comment: @Dan Thank you for the link. As far as I understand, it is not applicable here.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Thank you for the suggestion. I see your point and it does make a sence. And that is how I implemented it for now. On the other hand, having ~15 almoust the same functions is kinda contradicts to DRY principle and makes it painful to  add some minor changes.

Comment: Agreed, `__add__` and `__sub__` have only one character diff (`+` i/o `-`); yet, this difference is important enough to justify two full implementations of the methods.

Comment: Well, let's not confuse function name and function definition:) Infact, `__sub__` uses `__add__` method inside to not duplicate the code. For example, in python's source code https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/numbers.py#L91

Comment: Use a decorator on the class or a metaclass... or maybe [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) to dynamically define the functions (but that is ugly)

Answer (score 1):

This (broad) sort of problem is the purpose of the `operator` module:

```
import operator
def mkop(f):    # the usual scope for a closure
  def op(self,o):
    if isinstance(o,type(self)): raise …
    return type(self)(matrix=f(self.matrix,o),
                      metadata=self.metadata)
  return op
for op in ['add','sub',…]:
  setattr(A,"__%s__"%op,mkop(getattr(operator,op)))
```

You can also use `locals()[…]=mkop(…)` (in one of its rare safe uses) to do the above while defining the class.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to you use the `decorator` in this situation. May be this is not so short but you will save the readability of your code.

```py
import numpy as np

def decorator(fn):
    def ret_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(args[1], type(args[0])):
            raise ValueError("Not allowed.")
        else:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return ret_fn

class A:
    def __init__(self, matrix, metadata: list):
        self.matrix = np.array(matrix)
        self.metadata = metadata

    @decorator
    def __add__(self, other):
        return A(
            matrix=self.matrix.__add__(othe),
            metadata=self.metadata,
        )
```

The result:

```py
>>> a1 = A([[1], [2]], [])
>>> a2 = a1 + [[3], [4]]
>>> print(a2.matrix)
[[4]
 [6]]
>>> a1 + a1
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    raise ValueError("Not allowed.")
ValueError: Not allowed.
```

I don't know how many difference between your functions but you may rewrite decorator and the function pretty minimalistic:

**decorator**

```py
def decorator(fn):
    def ret_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(args[1], type(args[0])):
            raise ValueError("Not allowed.")
        else:
            return A(
                    matrix=fn(*args, **kwargs),
                    metadata=args[0].metadata,
                )

    return ret_fn
```

**the method**

```py
@decorator
def __add__(self, other):
    return self.matrix.__add__(other)
```