# Simulate "button pressed" an rise an event in gpiozero

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, gpiozero

I try to develop some code on a machine without GPIO. As GPIO library I selected a gpiozero to be able to write my code without access to gpio of raspberry pi.
My problem, I cant get ride of .when_pressed event in the code.
I simulate state change of the button, but the function is not called.

```
Device.pin_factory = MockFactory()

def interrupt_Event(channel):
   print("%s puted in the queue", channel)

InputPin.Device.pin_factory.pin(channel)
InputPin.when_pressed  = interrupt_Event

def main():
   try:
        while True:

            time.sleep(1)
                    InputPins[channel].pull=drive_high()
                    time.sleep(0.1) 
                    print("State CHANNEL %s" % channel)
                    print(InputPins[channel].state)
                    InputPins[channel].drive_low()
```

Till now I have no Idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when_pressed function should not have arguments (see 2.7 in https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html).

You could define the callback using a loop :[Creating functions in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop)
(use channel=channel to force early binding of channel value as in example below)

```
for channel in channels:
    def onpress(channel=channel):
        print("%s puted in the queue", channel)
    InputPins[channel].when_pressed = onpress
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced that you are using drive_high and drive_low to simulate the button pushing.
I have a almost identical problem. using Mock pins to develop a Pi program on windows, I find that the callback routines are not called.

```
from gpiozero.pins.mock import MockFactory
from gpiozero import Device, Button, LED
from time import sleep

Device.pin_factory = MockFactory()  # set default pin 
factory

btn = Button(16)

# Get a reference to mock pin 16 (used by the button)
btn_pin = Device.pin_factory.pin(16)

def pressed():       #  callback 
    print('pressed')

def released():       #  callback 
    print('released')    

btn.when_pressed  = pressed  
btn.when_released = released  # callback routine

for i in range(3):           # now try to signal sensor
    print('pushing the button')
    btn_pin.drive_high
    sleep(0.1)
    btn_pin.drive_low
    sleep(0.2)
```

The output has no callbacks, just

```
pushing the button

pushing the button

pushing the button
>>>
```

Comment: You are not _calling_ `drive_high()` and `drive_low()`, then of course they are not doing anything.