# how to generate functions in a for loop and use them for several inputs

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I want to run a function in a for loop. Firstly, I have a list of arrays and each arry includes some constants. These constants go to function. Then, I make  function and finally import arrays stored as a list into the created function. At the moment it is only using the constants stored in the last array of the list storing constants. I want to create the first function using the first array of `constants` and run that function for the first array of `inps`. I have checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop) but I could not solve my issue.

```
constants=[np.array([2., 2., 2., 2.]),
           np.array([20., 40., 30., 10.])]
inps=[np.array([[1., 1., 1.],[2., 2., 2.]]),
      np.array([[3., 3., 3.],[4., 4., 4.]])]
```

This is my code:

```
def fun(row=i):
    row[0] = a * row[0]
    for i in constants:
        i=i.tolist()
        a = i[0]
        return row[0], row[1], row[2]
    out=[]
    for j in inps:
        j=[j]
        new = np.asarray(list(map(fun, [x for point in j for x in point])))
        out.append(new)
```

Then, I want to get:

```
out= [np.array([[2.,  1.,  1.],
                [4.,  2.,  2.]]),
      np.array([[60.,  3. ,  3. ],
                [80.,  4. ,  4. ]])]
```

Simply, I want to multiply first value of the first array of `constants` to first column of first array of `inps` and replace it with the result. Then, I want to multiply the second of `constants` tothe second array of `inps` and so on.
But my code is creating only one function and performs the last function created by the cnstants coming from `constants[lasti]` for all the arrays of `inps`.
It is giving me the following result:

```
[array([[40.,  1.,  1.],
        [80.,  2.,  2.]]),
 array([[120.,   3.,   3.],
        [160.,   4.,   4.]])]
```

In advance, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Function should be defined before the for loop, and called from within it

Comment: @Dear LouieC, I tried your solution but still I have the same result.

Comment: " I have checked this solution but I could not solve my issue." I don't understand why not. What happened when you tried to apply the advice given in the answers there?

Comment: Dear @Karl Knechtel, based on the solution I tried to put `row=i` in my function but it did not solve my issue.

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Comment: dear@gmdev, I am getting it: `[array([[-1.6,  1. ,  1. ],
        [-3. ,  2. ,  2. ]]),
 array([[-4.4,  3. ,  3. ],
        [-5.8,  4. ,  4. ]])]`. The problem is that the same function is performed which is also created by the last array of `constants` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you need the function at all. This produces the output you are looking for:

```py
import numpy as np


constants = [
    np.array([2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]),
    np.array([20.0, 40.0, 30.0, 10.0])]
inps = [
    np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]]),
    np.array([[3.0, 3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0, 4.0]]),
]


for index, inp in enumerate(inps):
    inp[:,0] *= constants[index][0]

print(inps)
```

Output:

```py
[array([[2., 1., 1.],
        [4., 2., 2.]]),
 array([[60.,  3.,  3.],
        [80.,  4.,  4.]])]
```