# Dynamically adding class methods in Python

Tags: python, function, loops

I am trying to add class members to a class based on another, and I'm running into some issues with the loop.  All of the functions assigned wind up calling the last function found.

```
import inspect
from pprint import pp
from functools import wraps


def action(f):
    f.action = True
    return f


class x1:
    @action
    def func1(self):
        return 1

    def func2(self):
        return 2

    @action
    def func3(self):
        return 3


class x2:
    pass


funcs = inspect.getmembers(x1, predicate=inspect.isfunction)

for fn, f in funcs:
    if getattr(f, 'action', False):
        @wraps(f)
        def call(self):
            print(fn)
            return f(self)
        setattr(x2, fn, call)

a = x2()

pp({
    'funcs': [a.func1, a.func3],
    'func1': a.func1(),
    'func3': a.func3()
})
```

Output is:

```
func3
func3
{'funcs': [<bound method x1.func1 of <__main__.x2 object at 0x7f33eade1fd0>>,
           <bound method x1.func3 of <__main__.x2 object at 0x7f33eade1fd0>>],
 'func1': 3,
 'func3': 3}
```

...when obviously `func1` should return 1, not 3.

Comment: This should answer your question: [Creating functions in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop)

Comment: Subtle. You're using the name `f` from the outer scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `call` prints name `fn` and executes the name `f` from the global scope, which, at the end of your loop, are `'func3'` and `func3`:

```
def call(self):
    print(fn)
    return f(self)
```

The are a couple of ways to fix that. A popular method is too create a closure to preserve the right references in the enclosing scope:

```
def get_f(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def call(self):
        print(f.__name__)
        return f(self)
    return call
for fn, f in funcs:
    if getattr(f, 'action', False):
        setattr(x2, fn, get_f(f))
```

You could stash the reference in any other number of ways, for example:

```
def call(self, f=f):
    print(f.__name__)
    return f(self)
```

Just don't call a name in the global scope that you're using as a loop variable.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than tagging functions with a boolean attribute, I would just collected the decorated functions in a list. You can then attach the *functions* directly to `x2`, rather than messing around with `inspect` or wrappers.

```
from pprint import pp


def action(lst):
    def _(f):
        lst.append(f)
        return f
    return _


class x1:
    shared = []

    @action(shared)
    def func1(self):
        return 1

    @action(shared)
    def func2(self):
        return 2

    @action(shared)
    def func3(self):
        return 3


class x2:
    pass


for f in x1.shared:
    setattr(x2, f.__name__, f)
    

a = x2()

pp({
    'funcs': [a.func1, a.func3],
    'func1': a.func1(),
    'func3': a.func3()
})
```

Your problem is that `f` in `call` is a free variable, *not* the current value of `f` in the loop defining the functions. Every `call` refers to whatever `f` was last set to, in this case `func3`.