# Is there a way to solve a non-linear equation in nested arrays?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, nonlinear-equation

I want to solve for `m` the following equation numerically on Python:

```
C_left = np.cosh(m*(T/2 - t))/np.cosh( m*(T/2 - T - 1) ).
```

In this case, `C_left` is a nested array of floats with dimensions 15 x 47 and T = 48.
My intend outcome is a nested array `sol` with the same dimensions as `C_left`, in which the entries are the solutions to the above equation. For example, `sol[0]` has to contain the solutions for `C_left[0]` element/array (`sol[0][2]` is the solution for the element `C_left[0][2]`).

I have been trying to use the several equation solving functionalities that scipy offer, for example `scipy.optimize.fsolve` and `scipy.optimize.bisect`.

My most promising attempt was solving for only one element at a time, for example:

```
import scipy.optimize 
T = 48

C_left = [[C_all[j][t]/C_all[j][t+1] for t in range(47)] for j in range(15)]

def func1(m):
    return C_left[0][2] - np.cosh(m*(T/2 - 2))/np.cosh( m*(T/2 - T - 1) ) 

test = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func1,0.5)
```

and still I encountered the error:

```
RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last five Jacobian evaluations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
```

even though it actually outputted a solution!

My main problem is that I can't seem to figure out a way to solve this without unfolding the gigantic multidimensional array.

If anyone needs, I can provide the text for the 15 x 47 array.

EDIT: A new attempt !

Using the following answer [Creating functions in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-in-a-loop) , I was able to create a for loop that creates a function for each element of `C_left`. Then, I used those functions to solve the equation using `scipy.optimize.fsolve`.

```
import scipy.optimize 

T = 48
C_left = [[C_all[j][t]/C_all[j][t+1] for t in range(47)] for j in range(15)]
den = T/2 - T - 1

sol = [[0]*47]*15

def func_fac(m):
    def f():
        z = C_left[k][j] - np.cosh(m*(T/2 - j))/np.cosh(m*den)
        return z
    return f

for k in range(15):
    for j in range(47):
        sol[k][j] = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func_fac,0.5)
```

But I encountered another error

```
error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```