# Creating dictionary of lambda functions from pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda

I have a `dummy_calcurve.csv` file with parameters for a set of calibration curves as follows:

```
repeat,method,slope,intercept
a,linear,2,3
b,linear,4,5
```

I want to get a `calcurve : dict` of `lambda`-functions from this, such that I can calibrate for condition `'a'` as follows: `y=calcurve['a'](x)`.

I did the following:

```
calcurve = {}
ccs = pd.read_csv('dummy_calcurve.csv', index_col=0)
for repeat in ccs.index:
    slope = ccs.slope[repeat]
    intercept = ccs.intercept[repeat]
    print(repeat, slope, intercept)
    calcurve[repeat] = lambda x : slope * x + intercept
print(calcurve['a'](0))
print(calcurve['b'](0))
>>> a 2 3
>>> b 4 5
>>> 5
>>> 5
```

I would expect the final outputs to be `3` and `5`. In other words, both calibration curves appear to be the second one (for `b`), while the intermediate print statements suggest otherwise.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do lambda function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture) and [Creating functions (or lambdas) in a loop (or comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3431676/4046632)

Comment: Also [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Comment: This is very interesting! This is apparently normal behavior. I will read into your links. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 1

When adding the following, it works as expected.

```
def calibration(slope, intercept):
    return lambda x : slope * x + intercept

calcurve = {}
ccs = pd.read_csv('dummy_calcurve.csv', index_col=0)
for repeat in ccs.index:
    slope = ccs.slope[repeat]
    intercept = ccs.intercept[repeat]
    print(repeat, slope, intercept)
    calcurve[repeat] = calibration(slope, intercept)
>>> print(calcurve['a'](0))
>>> print(calcurve['b'](0))
>>> a 2 3
>>> b 4 5
>>> 3
>>> 5
```

I do not understand why this makes any difference.

EDIT 2 The following also fixes the issue.

```
calcurve = {}
ccs = pd.read_csv('dummy_calcurve.csv', index_col=0)
for repeat in ccs.index:
    slope = ccs.slope[repeat]
    intercept = ccs.intercept[repeat]
    print(repeat, slope, intercept)
    calcurve[repeat] = lambda x, s=slope, i=intercept : s * x + i
print(calcurve['a'](0))
print(calcurve['b'](0))

>>> a 2 3
>>> b 4 5
>>> 3
>>> 5
```

According to the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result), this is global/local scope issue. The `slope` and `intercept` parameters are not local to the `lambda` and thus are being updated everywhere during every loop. By making an extra variable `i` and `s`, these do become local. For the same reason, adding another layer with the `calibration`-function, which makes the `slope` and `intercept` local as well, fixes the issue as well.