# Given f and g, what's the difference between "lambda x: f(g(x))" and "(lambda h: lambda x: f(h(x)))(g)"?

Tags: python, recursion, lambda

**Background**: In Python, I'm trying writing a generator function that yields functions that are repeated applications of a one-argument function f. The first function yielded should apply f 0 times (the identity function), the second function yielded should apply f once, etc. **The function's doctest string is in the following**.

```
def repeated(f):
    """
    >>> double = lambda x: 2 * x
    >>> funcs = repeated(double)
    >>> identity = next(funcs)
    >>> double = next(funcs)
    >>> quad = next(funcs)
    >>> oct = next(funcs)
    >>> quad(1)
    4
    >>> oct(1)
    8
    >>> [g(1) for _, g in
    ...  zip(range(5), repeated(lambda x: 2 * x))]
    [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
    """
```

```
def repeated(f):
    g = lambda x: x
    while 1:
        yield g
        g = lambda x: f(g(x))
```

**Problem**: In the code above, max recursion depth error on line "g = lambda x: f(g(x))". But when I change that line to "g = (lambda h: lambda x: f(h(x)))(g)", it works. Why does this happen? What's the difference between these two statements?

```
def repeated(f):
    g = lambda x: x
    while 1:
        yield lambda x: g(x)
        g = (lambda h: lambda x: f(h(x)))(g)
```

**Extra Problem**:The code block above almost passes the doctest, but still fails.
Failed example:
quad(1)
Expected:
4
Got:
8

However, when I replace the "yield lambda x: g(x)" to "yield g", it passes the doctest. What's the difference between "lambda x: g(x)" and "g"?

Comment: This issue seems like it is caused by late binding. Can you try `lambda x, f=f, g=g: f(g(x))`, and see if that solves your problem? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-or-lambdas-in-a-loop-or-comprehension

Comment: awesome! I explored the link, you are totally right, the suggestion works!

Comment: Long story short: almost every other language uses scoped names, but python uses dynamic names instead. Confusion ensues.