# How to have a lambda function evaluate a variable now (and not postponed)

Tags: python, lambda, closures, bottle, getattr

I have a class for a hardware object (here Fridge), and I'd like to automatically create HTTP API routes for a given subset of Fridge's methods, here `open` and `close`.

```
from bottle import Bottle, request

class Fridge:
    def _not_exposed(self):
        print("This one is never called via HTTP")
    def open(self, param1=None, param2=None):
        print("Open", param1, param2)
    def close(self):
        print("Close")
    # + many other methods

f = Fridge()
app = Bottle("")

for action in ["open", "close"]:
    app.route(f"/action/{action}", callback=lambda: (getattr(f, action)(**request.query)))

app.run()
```

It works, except that in

```
...callback=lambda: (getattr(f, action)(**request.query))
```

`action` is evaluated *when the lambda function is called*.

Thus when opening http://127.0.0.1:8080/action/open?param1=123, the lambda is called, and at this time `action` has the value ... `"close"` (the last value in the `for` enumeration), then `getattr(f, action)` links to `f.close` instead of `f.open`. This is not what we want!

**Question: in this lambda definition, how to have `action` evaluated now, and not postponed?**

Expected behaviour for the `for` loop:

```
app.route("/action/open", callback=lambda: f.open(**request.query)))
app.route("/action/close", callback=lambda: f.close(**request.query)))
```

Comment: Use a default arg in the lambda: `lambda action=action: ..`. Default arguments are bound to a function at definition time.

Comment: @user2390182 Oh right. I think you can post this as an answer!

Comment: `app.route(f"/action/{action}", callback=(lambda action=action: lambda: getattr(f, action)(**request.query)))`

Comment: I think I will close this as a dupe. This a super common question here ;)

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures This as quick read.

Comment: @Obaskly why a double lambda? It seems this works: `...callback=lambda action=action: (getattr(f, action)(**request.query))`

Comment: You don't need a "default arg" in this case, just remove the ``lambda``, your ``getattr(f, action)`` is the callable itself

Comment: @Meitham Can you give more details, I don't exactly understand your comment :) By what should I replace `callback=lambda: (getattr(f, action)(**request.query))` with your method?