# In Python, how can I avoid non-local variables referenced in functions that change with assignments outside the function?

Tags: python

For example, I want to implement a function that takes one argument, n, which returns a series of functions that return, in order, 0, 1, 2, ... , n-1, if I implement it in the following way:

```py
def outer(n):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        def inner():
            return i
        res.append(inner)
    return res
```

Then these functions will all return the last number, which is n-1. I know this is because `i` in the `inner` function is actually just a reference to `i` in the `outer` function, which will be reassigned with iteration. Is there any way to solve this problem?

One possible solution I've found so far is this:

```py
def outer(n):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        def inner(i = i):
            return i
        res.append(inner)
    return res
```

By using a default argument, i is computed at function definition time. However, in my opinion, this approach is not elegant because it introduces an unnecessary default parameter.

Comment: You define an inner function inside a for loop. Then, in your loop, you add functions to the list. I wonder why you use this approach. Normally, an inner function is defined before the loop in which it is used. Then the same function is called multiple times with arguments inside a loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating functions (or lambdas) in a loop (or comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-or-lambdas-in-a-loop-or-comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid returning functions with unnecessary parameters with default values, you can enclose the inner function in an additional closure:

```
def closure(x):
    def inner():
        return x
    return inner

def outer(n):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        res.append(closure(i))
    return res

for f in outer(3):
    print(f())
```

This outputs:

```
0
1
2
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/28oC4b

Comment: `def closure(x)` should be outside the for loop, probably even outside of `outer`

Comment: Indeed, I was meaning to replace the OP's `inner` function with a different version so I placed it where the OP put it, but you're absolutely right that there's no reason to put the function definition in the loop when using a closure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

blhsing's answer shows how you could wrap your inner function returning a fixed value.

I'll go with an answer that underneath still uses a parameter, but flexible fixes it by using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).
In the end also a wrapper. Depending on if the parameter is is given to partial as a positional parameter or a keyword the resulting function is parameter-less (assuming no other parameters beside) or a keyword-only function.

```
from functools import partial # works like a factory to create new functions.

def _inner(i): # your constant function
   return i

def outer(n):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        # res.append(partial(_inner, i=i)) # partial fixes the current value for the function as keyword-only argument
        res.append(partial(_inner, i)) # alternative, parameter-less version
    return res
```

Comment: `partial` does not create a parameter-less function. It merely gives existing parameters default values. Demo: https://ideone.com/dKECqW

Comment: Depends on the case. If the parameter is given as positional its fixed and not in the signature. If its given as keyword to partial it becomes a keyword-only parameter.