Python dictionary keeps repeating last value of lambda function after for loop
For an optimisation function from scipy i need a specific dictionary-tuple for the constraints.
Because I don't know how many variables i am using, the equations array could be of size 1x1,2x2,3x3,4x4,... and so on. So the number and size of the constraints can change, therefore the for loop.
This is the part of my code that doesn't work how it should.
import numpy as np

equations = np.array([[ 0.,          1.,         -1.,        ],
                        [-0.9486833,  -0.31622777, -0.63245553],
                        [-0.70710678, -0.70710678, -0.70710678],
                        [ 0.9486833,  -0.31622777, -0.63245553],
                        [ 0.70710678, -0.70710678, -0.70710678]])

constraints = [dict() for x in range(0,equations.shape[0])]

for i in range(0,equations.shape[0]):
    eq = equations[i,:]
    constraints[i] = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: np.dot( -eq[:-1] , x ) -eq[-1] }
    print( constraints[i]['fun']((1,1)) )

for i in range(0,len(constraints)):
    print( constraints[i]['fun']((1,1)) )

The current output is:
0.0
1.8973666000000002
2.12132034
0.0
0.70710678
0.70710678
0.70710678
0.70710678
0.70710678
0.70710678

but should be:
0.0
1.8973666000000002
2.12132034
0.0
0.70710678
0.0
1.8973666000000002
2.12132034
0.0
0.70710678

So the last value keeps repeating.
Similar questions have been asked before, and the solution was something like "create a copy" or "define dictionary inside loop" but this does not work for me.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431676/creating-functions-or-lambdas-in-a-loop-or-comprehension

Try: constraints[i] = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, eq=eq: np.dot( -eq[:-1] , x ) -eq[-1]} as that will set eq at definition rather than call.

thanks, this did also help:
https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

The way I like to think of this is that you probably already understand what is going on here. Suppose I define a function, def foo(): print(x). Then, what do you expect the output of the following to be? x = 1; foo(); x = 99; foo()
