# Always given command line before python fabric command is executed on remote

Tags: python, ubuntu, deployment, fabric, rackspace

I'm just starting to use python fabric to run commands on remote rackspace ubuntu servers. I can't run a command without getting the command line requiring my input. This is the sequence how I can recreate the problem.

I do not have any trouble connecting to the remote machine with ssh using keys and no passwords.

This is my fabfile.py

```
from fabric.api import env, run

env.hosts = ['remote.ip.address']
env.user = 'http'

def hello():
    run("touch hello.world")
```

The command I use to run the fabfile.py (uses python 2.7 virtualenv)

```
$ ~/env/py27/bin/fab -f code/fabfile.py hello
```

This is the command line showing how it always gets stuck and requires me to type exit.

```
[remote.ip.address] Executing task 'hello'
[remote.ip.address] run: touch hello.world
[remote.ip.address] out: http@server-name:~$
```

I can exit the remote terminal by typing exit and the command will run and I'll be returned to my local terminal.

```
[remote.ip.address] out: exit
[remote.ip.address] out: 

Done.
Disconnecting from remote.ip.address... done.
me@local-computer: $
```

And this is the method I used to set up ssh keys to not require passwords. https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1626/Using+SSH+keys+on+your+server

Comment: yeah this is kinda weird... did you try setting the host string in the code? See Toby Champion's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326797/how-to-set-target-hosts-in-fabric-file) for what I mean

Comment: Just ran through this exact code as well on a fresh Ubuntu box. I do have to wait for a bit for it to run. I did add env.password, I could test with keys next.

Comment: Edited Question to include the method I used to set up SSH keys. I'm not sure whats causing this to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I don't have such issue, your code works fine for me (up to adding `env.key_filename` and `env.password`)

```
c:\work>fab hello
[x.x.x.x] Executing task 'hello'
[x.x.x.x] run: touch hello.world

Done.
Disconnecting from x.x.x.x... done.
```

I'm using Fabric 1.7.0 and Paramiko 1.11.0. 
Possibly it's a problem of the terminal on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out.

I had edited my ~/.profile file to inclue the "bash" command so that bash would be the default shell. I've copied the old version of the ~/.profile file below. Since fabric leads all of its commands with /bin/bash it was essentially starting two bash prompts and only exiting one. After I removed the bash command from the server everything works fine.

This is the bash file with the extra bash command.

```
bash  #REMOVE THIS LINE AND FABRIC WORKS

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```