# parallel running in fabric python

Tags: python, fabric

I want to run a method on several remote hosts in parallel through Python script.
I have their credential (ip,usr,pass).
in order to do it I decorate the method with `@parallel`, and called it via `execute()` where I gave all hosts.
my question is how do I set `env.usr`, `env.password` for each task?
here is an example of my code:

```
class deployment()

    __init__():
        self.hosts = read_ips_from_csv

    def do_something(self)
       run(remote_command)

    def run_remote(self,func):
       execute(func,hosts = self.hosts) 

    def deploy(self):
       run_remote(self.do_something)

main():

my_deploy = deployment()
my_deploy.deploy()
```

the question is how to set the `env` parameters for each host in `do_something()`

thanks a lot for your answers!!

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this is how i solve it (found it in another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/5568219/3216763 ):
i added env.hosts and env password before calling the execute like this:

```
def run_remote(self,func):
    env.hosts = ['user1@host1:port1', 'user2@host2.port2']
    env.passwords = {'user1@host1:port1': 'password1', 'user2@host2.port2': 'password2'}
    execute(func)
```

spent quite time on it so maybe it will help others.

Comment: If you found a solution from another stackoverflow question, you should include a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

- At least for the login, this can be sent along with the hostname as explained in [How to set target hosts in Fabric file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326797/how-to-set-target-hosts-in-fabric-file).
- I haven't found a simple way to do that for passwords. This is certainly monkey-patchable.

Note that the preferred way to do that is to use SSH keys with help you get rid of all this in a very simple way

Comment: Note that the preferred way to do that is to use SSH keys with help you get rid of all this in a very simple way.                          can you clarify?

Comment: SSH keys allows you to log on several password protected ssh account using a same password you decide. Usage of a ssh keys boils down to generating a ssh key, putting its public version on each server and adding `env.key_filename = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"` to your fabfile. For more information about ssh keys, Google is your friend (this box feels largely too small for such a discussion :))...

Comment: thanks! i solved it this time but will sure look at your suggestion.