# How to dynamically edit env.roledefs in Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326797/how-to-set-target-hosts-in-fabric-file) but it doesn't answer to my problem.

I would like to do something like:

```
@task
def setEnv(environment):
    if environment == 'prod':
        env.roledefs['nginx'] = [ 'www@tnginx01', 'www@tnginx02' ]
        env.roledefs['middle'] = [ 'www@tmiddle01', 'www@tmiddle02' ]
    elif environment == 'preprod':
        env.roledefs['nginx'] = [ 'www@pnginx01', 'www@pnginx02' ]
        env.roledefs['middle'] = [ 'www@pmiddle01', 'www@pmiddle02' ]
    else:
        puts(red("This environment doesn't exist. Possible values are 'preprod' and 'prod'", True))
        sys.exit()

    env.first_middle = env.roledefs['middle'][0]

@task
@roles(env.first_middle)
def deploy():
    run('pwd')
```

But it seems that it's not possible to change the value of env.roledefs after the Fabfile has been loaded into memory.
When you try to run `fab setEnv:prod deploy`, it won't work:

> No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection

Does anyone know how to do that? Note that I cannot use roledefs to represent environments. I already use roledefs to store servers belonging to a same 'cluster', and each environment has several clusters with several servers.

Comment: So to be clear, you cannot set env.roledefs['first_middle'] = env.roledefs['middle'][:1], and set @roles('first_middle')?

Comment: Yes, I can, but this wouldn't solve the problem of env.roledefs which cannot be edited from within a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem.

The key is that **env.roledefs** cannot be edited from within a Fabric task. So, the code editing it has to be at the beginning **in the global scope**.

```
if env.get('env') == 'prod':
    env.roledefs['nginx'] = [ 'www@tnginx01', 'www@tnginx02' ]
    env.roledefs['middle'] = [ 'www@tmiddle01', 'www@tmiddle02' ]
elif env.get('env') == 'preprod':
    env.roledefs['nginx'] = [ 'www@pnginx01', 'www@pnginx02' ]
    env.roledefs['middle'] = [ 'www@pmiddle01', 'www@pmiddle02' ]
else:
    puts(red("This environment doesn't exist. Possible values are 'preprod' and 'prod'", True))
    sys.exit()

    env.first_middle = env.roledefs['middle'][0]

@task
@roles(env.first_middle)
def deploy():
    run('pwd')
```

And then I just call the fabfile like this:

```
fab --set env=preprod deploy
```

My answer is inspired from [this link](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/fab-user/2012-12/msg00026.html) which gave me the idea.

Comment: Just in case someone finds this answer: You _can_ set/manipulate env.roledefs inside a task (if you call such a task from another task, don't forget to use execute()). The code in the question should throw an AttributeError, env has no "first_middle" at the time of the decorator definition (and in the answer above setting env.first_middle shouldn't be indented). Fox I think you drew the wrong conclusions.